# Is this number triangular?

Tags: code-golf, number, decision-problem

### Challenge

Given a positive integer, determine whether it is a triangular number, and accordingly output one of any two constant, distinct values.

#### Definition

A [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) is a number that can be expressed as the sum of consecutive positive integers, starting at 1. They can also be expressed with the formula \$\frac {n(n + 1)}  2\$, where \$n\$ is some positive integer.

### Test cases

Truthy:

```
1
3
6
10
15
21
55
276
1540
2701
5050
7626
18915
71253
173166
222111
303031
307720
500500
998991
```

Falsy:

```
2
4
5
7
8
9
11
16
32
50
290
555
4576
31988
187394
501500
999999
```

### Rules

- Your entry may be a function or a program.
- You may assume that the input is a positive integer under \$10^6\$.
- You must pick two constant, distinct outputs to distinguish the two categories.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so **the shortest code in bytes in each language wins.**

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/118361/42545), [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/121731/42545).

Comment: [Related OEIS sequence](https://oeis.org/A010054)

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/118980/58974)

Comment: Why didn't you include zero?

Comment: @Neil I wanted to minimize the number of possible edge cases, and handling zero is one of them that I felt wasn't too important. Do you think it would have been better if zero needed to be handled? (The Jelly answer currently fails on zero, for instance)

Comment: Bah, I would have thought programmers would have learned how to count starting at zero by now.

Comment: So, would an integer which is truthy in our language not count?

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala There is no requirement that your output values be truthy or falsy, but you can only have two of them.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/99688/polygonal-numbers)

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/133109/58826)

Comment: [Would this be a valid output for non-triangular numbers?](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=KjjEIKx5&input=LW1SClsxLAozLAo2LAoxMCwKMTUsCjIxLAo1NSwKMjc2LAoxNTQwLAoyNzAxLAo1MDUwLAo3NjI2LAoxODkxNSwKNzEyNTMsCjE3MzE2NiwKMjIyMTExLAozMDMwMzEsCjMwNzcyMCwKNTAwNTAwLAo5OTg5OTEsCjIsCjQsCjUsCjcsCjgsCjksCjExLAoxNiwKMzIsCjUwLAoyOTAsCjU1NSwKNDU3NiwKMzE5ODgsCjE4NzM5NCwKNTAxNTAwLAo5OTk5OTld)

Comment: Is zero for truthy and non-zero for falsy/vice versa allowed?

Answer (score 30):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 23 bytes

EDIT:

- -1 byte: @xnor got rid of parentheses with a `$`.

An anonymous function taking an `Int` and returning a `Char`.

Output is `'1'` for triangular numbers and `'0'` for others.

```hs
(!!)$show.(10^)=<<[0..]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#JY3risJADIX/@xRH6Y@W4pBkOpeA9UVcF8pasbCOS@vi43cjm0BufCfnPkyln8pznIevZ/VbvqcyLu4@/NQfZX8sbbvD/ohd256u1TwOF5Rz416P@bKs177ebptquT1ermb6bPrD4UTOndeV4RHBBA4QRrCabA8d2UB2oEBIUeyW1ZjEEjw4eY4RIsJsH8jy3VISMoVJCKpZlTeCDqZChsJQjvBiCESNNLcumJ1nzdkMklejif/179j8AQ)

- Use as `((!!)$show.(10^)=<<[0..]) 998991`.
- Generates the numbers 1, 10, 100, 1000, ..., converts those to strings, and concatenates them. Then indexes into the resulting infinite string

  ```hs
  "1101001000100001000001000000...
  ```

Comment: An imaginative method! You can save a byte with `(!!)$show.(10^)=<<[0..]`.

Answer (score 22):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/), 24 bytes

```python
lambda n:(8*n+1)**.5%1>0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#S7ON@Z@TmJuUkqiQZ6VhoZWnbaippaVnqmpoZ/A/Lb9IIU8hM0@hKDEvPVXDUMfSUlNBWyHa1MAAiIA8C0tLQx1TA0MIDwRirbg4C4oy80oU8nTSNPI0/wMA)

Outputs `False` for triangular numbers, `True` for the rest. Checks if `8*n+1` is a perfect square. Python's float precision for square roots easily suffices for the challenge limits of `n` up to a million, first giving a false positive on `n=6896076976160002` as found by Deadcode.

Comment: `(1<<10000)**.5`: OverflowError: int too large to convert to float

Comment: @isaacg The challenge doesn't require inputs that large: "You may assume that the input is a positive integer under 10^6"

Comment: @trichoplax I think I was disputing xnor's claim in the text. The submission is fine, I agree.

Comment: Python does *not* do arbitrary-precision exponentiation with `**` unless both operands are integer. Otherwise it uses IEEE 374. This function reports both `6896076976160001` and its successor, `6896076976160002`, as being triangular (that is the smallest number with which it fails).

Comment: @Deadcode Thanks, I stand corrected. I edited the post.

Comment: @Deadcode You mean 754? I don't see a 374.

Comment: @S.S.Anne My bad, it is IEEE 754. Don't know how I made a typo like that.

Answer (score 14):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly)

```
R+\ċ
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@x@kHXOk@//RPYfbHzWtcf//P9pQx1jHTMfQQMfQVMfIUMcUSOqY6JjqmOtY6hga6hia6Rgb6ZgaxAIA)**

#### How?

```
R+\ċ - Main link: n
R    - range(n)   -> [1,2,3,...,N]
  \  - cumulative reduce by:
 +   -   addition -> [1,3,6,...,T(N)]
   ċ - count occurrences of right (n) in left -> 1 if triangular, 0 otherwise
```

Comment: I'm surprised cumulative reduce doesn't automatically make a range. Is there a design choice behind this?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I think it would (at least currently) need to by the dyadic operation being reduced over that would cause a range to be made.

Comment: ...actually even that does not seem to apply (e.g. [this](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@18Q8////2hDHSMd41gA) vs [this](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@18Q8///f2MA). It seems the quicklink implementation overrides such that the iterable does not make a range even if the dyadic operation defines it to do so for an argument. Pinged Dennis to field this one :)

Comment: @ETHproductions `/` and ``\`` probably were among the first five quicks to be implemented, predating the idea to cast integer arguments to range.

Answer (score 14):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 10 bytes

```
(^1|1\1)+$
```

Input is in unary. Output is `0` or `1`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#FYvLCUMxEAPvU4cDTgyPle31p5dHSCHp3dlchDSMHvlzFdLr5Le@uvUs6RzRGMiQU4VHztjeLYoFMDfmqMHW/jt0nMliI6FBqyFRt8XZ6R73pr3WDw) (As a test suite that does decimal-to-unary conversion for convenience.)

#### Explanation

This is the most basic exercise in forward-references. Most people are familiar with backreferences in regex, e.g. `(.)\1` to match a repeated character. However, some of the more advanced flavours allow you to use a backreference before or inside the group it's referring to. In that case, it's usually called a forward-reference. This can make sense if the reference is repeated. It might not be well defined on the first iteration, but on subsequent iterations, the later or surrounding group has captured something and can be reused.

This is most commonly used to implement recurrent patterns on unary strings. In this case, we try to match the input as the sum of consecutive integers:

```
(        # This is group 1, which we'll repeat 1 or more times.
  ^1     #   Group 1 either matches a single 1 at the beginning of the string.
|        # or
  1\1    #   It matches whatever the previous iteration matched, plus another
         #   1, thereby incrementing our counter.
         # Note that the first alternative only works on the first iteration
         # due to the anchor, and the second alternative only works *after*
         # the first iteration, because only then the reference is valid.
)+
$        # Finally, we make sure that we can exactly hit the end of the
         # string with this process.
```

Comment: Why doesn't `(^|1\1)+$` work?

Comment: @LeakyNun regex engines have an optimisation that they stop repeating a group if it was empty **n** times where **n** is the minimum of the quantifier you're using (in your case 1; if the minimum was 0, it would be tried once anyway). If you change the `+` to `{2,}`, it should work. This optimisation prevents infinite loops but it's also the only thing that keeps .NET regex from being Turing-complete on its own.

Comment: This just saved me 70 bytes: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/118387

Comment: Make that 74 bytes, thanks to `\G`!

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 25 bytes

Checks if (**8x+1**) is a square number.

```python
lambda x:(8*x+1)**.5%1==0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#XZDNCsJADITvPkUvQltBkmy3uxH6Jl4qUhBURDz07Ws9yH66e5n8TGaSqRqq43Idb6fzWM2HOrfzTpu23cetDoMsj@fl/qqmWpvNF4YC@wJVgGPBBmZkPpEcO2FJSJKIWuqNvOzUSmoR7jQF7dFtZqpcRNb/E6dkQuVVGrF7dke/FdiBBT8FZoyBQ0xTOA1GF1B02uM5u8h7BvWceaYUnBZF/xb7vGZ5Aw)

Answer (score 8):

### Mathematica, 16 bytes

```
OddQ@Sqrt[1+8#]&
```

Essentially a port of xnor's [Python solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/122092/61980). Outputs `True` for triangular numbers, `False` otherwise.

Answer (score 7):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>30</s> 27 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to kamoroso94*

```js
f=(n,k)=>n>0?f(n+~k,-~k):!n
```

#### Test cases

```js
f=(n,k)=>n>0?f(n+~k,-~k):!n

console.log('Testing truthy test cases');
console.log(f(1))
console.log(f(3))
console.log(f(6))
console.log(f(10))
console.log(f(15))
console.log(f(21))
console.log(f(55))
console.log(f(276))
console.log(f(1540))
console.log(f(2701))
console.log(f(5050))
console.log(f(7626))
console.log(f(18915))
console.log(f(71253))
console.log(f(173166))
console.log(f(222111))
console.log(f(303031))
console.log(f(307720))
console.log(f(500500))
console.log(f(998991))

console.log('Testing falsy test cases');
console.log(f(2))
console.log(f(4))
console.log(f(5))
console.log(f(7))
console.log(f(8))
console.log(f(9))
console.log(f(11))
console.log(f(16))
console.log(f(32))
console.log(f(50))
console.log(f(290))
console.log(f(555))
console.log(f(4576))
console.log(f(31988))
console.log(f(187394))
console.log(f(501500))
console.log(f(999999))
```

#### Non-recursive version (ES7), 19 bytes

Port of [Adnan's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/122091/58563).

```js
x=>(8*x+1)**.5%1==0
```

Comment: Only seeing now that you edited the 19 byte solution into your answer a few minutes before I posted [mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/122102/58974). Should I delete mine? What's the generally accepted etiquette on that?

Comment: @Shaggy I don't think it's a real problem here. My 'main' answer really is the recursive one.

Comment: Reduce to 28 bytes with `f=(n,k=1)=>n>0?f(n-k,k+1):!n`?

Comment: @kamoroso94 Thanks! Updated. And a third byte was saved by omitting the initialization of `k`.

Comment: Elegant use of bitwise NOT as an incrementor for an initially-`undefined` value; your edit was a pleasure to read after I independently arrived at your prior solution.

Comment: The second answer is sort of useless since its neither a program nor a function. Maybe if it were `f=(x)=>...` that adds 4 bytes.

Comment: @Octopus The 2nd answer is an arrow function. The usual practice is to omit `f=` (or whatever function name) unless it's referenced in the function itself, like in the first answer which is a recursive one.

Comment: I know what an arrow function is, but I don't understand your reasoning. If you can omit the `f=` then why not also omit the `x=>`. You still get the gist and it is still useless code. Don't you have to be able to use it as-is?

Comment: @Octopus Using unnamed functions is allowed (please see [this meta answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7615/58563)). Omitting parameters is not. Or to put it in other words: the name of the function doesn't matter (you may even call it without naming it: `(x=>(8*x+1)**.5%1==0)(15)`) whereas the name of the parameters does matter (even if we can guess that it's `x` in a simple case like this one).

Comment: Okay, just trying to understand the rules. I was looking in meta for an answer.

Comment: @Octopus The rule as I've always understood is: if the challenge requires input, the submission must contain a mechanism for accepting input. this can either be done via arguments for a function submission or, if you choose not to use a function, by some explicit input mechanism like `prompt` (for JavaScript). What you can't do is say "assume this variable `x` has already been defined with the input..." -- it must either be that `x` is a formal argument whose value is provided when the function is called, or `x` must get its value explicitly in the code of the submission via user input.

Answer (score 7):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 40 bytes

```
(([{}](((()))<>))<>){<>({}({}({})))}{}{}
```

[Wheat Wizard](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/218449) and I had a [duel](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12423/57100) over this question. When we decided to post our solutions we were tied at 42 bytes, but I found a 2 byte golf of his solution. We decided that would count as the tie breaker (my solution is below).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#@6@hEV1dG6sBBJqamjZ2YFxtY6dRXQtBQNHaaiD8/9/QAAA)

#### Explanation:

```
# Set up the stacks like this:  -input
                                     1     -input
                                     1          1
(([{}](((()))<>))<>)                 ^

# Output 1 for triangular and 0 for non-triangular 
{<>({}({}({})))}{}{}
```

For a full explanation please see [Wheat Wizard's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/122226/57100).

---

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 42 bytes

```
(([({})])<>){(({}())<>{}({})){((<>))}{}{}}
```

Outputs `0\n` (literal newline) for truthy, and the empty string for falsy.

The idea is to subtract 1 then 2 then 3 all the way up to the input. If you hit 0, then you know this is a triangular number, so you can stop there.

[Try it online! (truthy)](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X0MjWqO6VjNW08ZOs1oDyNTQBDKBFFAQJAAU1qytBsLa//9NTQE)
[Try it online! (falsy)](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X0MjWqO6VjNW08ZOs1oDyNTQBDKBFFAQJAAU1qytBsLa//9NzQA)

```
# Push -input on both stacks. One is a counter and the other is a running total
(([({})])<>)

# Count up from -input to 0
{
  # Push the new total which is: (counter += 1) + total (popped) + input (not popped)
  # This effectively adds 1, then 2, then 3 and so on to the running total
  (({}())<>{}({}))
  # If not 0
  {
    # Push to 0s and switch stacks to "protect" the other values
    ((<>))
  # End if
  }
  # Pop the two 0s, or empty the stack if we hit 0
  {}{}
# End loop
}
```

---

#### Here's a 46 byte solution that I found interesting.

```
{<>(({}())){({}[()]<>{(<({}[()])>)}{}<>)}{}<>}
```

Outputs `0\n` (literal newline) for truthy, the empty string for falsy.

The idea is to count down from input by consecutive numbers, 1 at a time. E.g. `input - (1) - (1,1) - (1,1,1)`. Each time we subtract, if we aren't at 0 yet, we leave an extra value on the stack. That way, if we are at 0 and are still subtracting when we pop we remove the last value on the stack. If the input was a triangular number, we will end exactly at 0, and wont pop the 0.

[Try it online! truthy](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/v9rGTkOjulZDU1OzGkhHa2jG2thVa9hA2Zp2mrXVtTZQsvb/f1MDUwMA)
[Try it online! falsy](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/v9rGTkOjulZDU1OzGkhHa2jG2thVa9hA2Zp2mrXVtTZQsvb/fxNTczMA)

```
# Implicit input (call it I)

# Until we reach 0, or the stack is empty
{
  # Add 1 to the other stack and push it twice. This is our counter.
  <>(({}()))
  # While counter != 0
  {
    # counter -= 1
    ({}[()]
    # if I != 0 
    <>{
      # I -= 1, and push 0 to escape the if
      (<({}[()])>)
    # End if
    }
    # Pop from the stack with I. This is either the 0 from the if, or I
    {}
    # Get ready for next loop End while
    <>)
  # End While
  }
  # Pop the counter that we were subtracting from
  {}<>
# End Until we reach 0, or the stack is empty.
}
```

Answer (score 6):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 11 bytes

```
ri2*_mQ_)*=
```

Outputs `1` for triangular, `0` otherwise.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@1@UaaQVnxsYr6ll@/@/kSEA)

#### Explanation

Consider input `21`.

```
ri               e# Input integer.             STACK: 21
  2*             e# Multiply by 2.             STACK: 42
    _            e# Duplicate.                 STACK: 42, 42
     mQ          e# Integer square root.       STACK: 42, 6
       _)        e# Duplicate, increment.      STACK: 42, 6, 7
         *       e# Multiply.                  STACK: 42, 42
          =      e# Equal?                     STACK: 1
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
×8‘Æ²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#LY7LDQIxDETvVJECfLCdZB1XQBGr7QVxgBKgCE6UwHayjYQZRD4aa5w38dwf47g899vnPff7cX3hnOdcV5NSpSxSTHG7FIfTqUGzN2WpNLWjjsXpj@TbMO@gLaotcN3djIGK/dMIV5JAoZkj0zY5ldWlNDQQIWWggxAAhpDqBBCWJDlJ6xylWo7Bn6MmUbV/Jte2fQE)

#### Background

Let **n** be the input. If **n** is the **k**<sup>th</sup> triangular number, we have

$$ n = \frac{k(k+1)}{2} \iff k^2+k-2n = 0 \iff k = \frac12 (-1 \pm \sqrt{1+8n}), $$

which means there will be a natural solution if and only if **1 + 8n** is an odd, perfect square. Clearly, checking the parity of **1 + 8n** is not required.

#### How it works

```
×8‘Æ²  Main link. Argument: n

×8     Yield 8n.
  ‘    Increment, yielding 8n + 1.
   Æ²  Test if the result is a perfect square.
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 23 <s>24</s> <s>25</s> bytes

```
I1Wq/)s.;0..s;p-?\.+O@u
```

0 for truthy and nothing <s>0</s> for falsey.  Brutes forces by incrementing counter, adding to cumulative sum and comparing to input.  <s>Now to try and fit it on a 2x2x2 cube.</s> Did it!

```
    I 1
    W q
/ ) s . ; 0 . .
s ; p - ? \ . +
    O @
    u .
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cubix#@@9pGF6or1msZ22gp1dsXaBrH6On7e9Q@v@/IQA)

- `/` Reflect to to face.
- `I10\` get integer input, push 1 (counter), push 0 (sum) and reflect
- `+s;p-` loop body. Add sum and counter, drop previous sum, raise input and subtract
- `?` Test the result of the subtraction

  - For 0 result carrying on straight ahead `\.uO@` reflect to bottom face, no-op, U-turn, output and halt.
  - For positive result turn right onto bottom face and `@` halt
  - For negative result turn left `;qWs)/su` drop subtraction, put input to bottom, shift left, swap counter and sum, increment counter, reflect, swap sum and counter, U-turn onto main loop body.

Comment: So tantalizingly close... that last byte is going to take a lot of effort and cleverness though.

Comment: Yep, thought I had it but is being elusive

Comment: @ETHproductions found the byte

Comment: Your code and your unfolded cube appear to be different, the lower right corner is a `.` on the cube but a `1` in your code.

Comment: @WheatWizard  Thanks for that, bad editing on my part

Answer (score 5):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 42 bytes

```
(([{}](<((())<>)>))<>){<>({}({}({})))}{}{}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#@6@hEV1dG6tho6GhoalpY6dpByarbew0qmshSFNTs7YaCP//NzYDAA)

### Explanation

The goal of this program is to create a state on two stacks and perform constant operation on both stacks until one of them zeros, we can then output depending on which stack we are on.  This is similar to programs that determine the sign of a number. These programs put `n` on one stack and `-n` on the other and add one and switch stacks until one of the stacks is zero.  If the number was negative in the first place the first stack will hit zero, if the number was positive the other stack will hit zero.

Here we create two stacks one that subtracts consecutive numbers from the input and one that just subtracts one.  The one that subtracts consecutive numbers will only terminate if the number is triangular, (other wise it will just pass zero and keep going into the negatives).  The other one will always terminate for any positive number, but will always do so slower than the first, thus non-triangular numbers will terminate on that stack.

So how do we set up stacks so that the same operation subtracts consecutive numbers on one and subtracts one on the other?  On each stack we have the input on top so that in can be checked, below that we have the difference and below that we have the difference of the difference.  Each time we run we add the "difference of the difference" to the regular "difference" and subtract that from the input.  For the stack that checks for triangularity we set our double difference to be `1` so that we get consecutive integers each time we run, for the other stack we set it to `0` so that we never change the difference, that is it always stays 1.  Here is how the stack is set up at the beginning, where `n` is the input:

```
-n  -n
 0   1
 1   0
```

When we finally do terminate we can use these differences to check which stack we are on we pop the top two values and we get `1` for a triangular number and `0` for a non-triangular number.

---

#### Annotated code

```
(([{}](<((())<>)>))<>) Set up the stack
{                      While
 <>                    Switch stacks
 ({}({}({})))          Add bottom to second to bottom, add second to bottom to top
}                      End while
{}{}                   Pop the top two values
```

---

Here's a 50 byte solution I like as well.

```
{(({}[()]))}(([[]])<>){({}{}())<>}({}{()<><{}>}{})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#FcixCQAwDAPBdaQuTbqQRYwnEZrdUeCL40eAXGCTBqq6eS6VKYOxPxEc@WZyZq@VHg)

Answer (score 5):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>31</s> 30 bytes

```powershell
"$args"-in(1..1e6|%{($s+=$_)})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#@6@kkliUXqykm5mnYainZ5hqVqNaraFSrG2rEq9Zq/n//39TAwMgAgA)

Nice and slow brute force method. Make an array of every sum of 1 through 10<sup>6</sup>, and see if the argument is in there.

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>23</s> 19 bytes

Similar approach as other answers. Checks to see if `8x+1` is a perfect square.
 -4 bytes thanks Giuseppe and MickyT.

```r
!(8*scan()+1)^.5%%1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY1LCgJBDET3dQsXAzMKkkp3Op3LCOLehd6ftgYTyI9Xqc9al31ev6/nez9uPB732DYuomGABgacCNXUHt00mA4Whhyu2ywxSY8GZuMYcHdSH0x5tkw3KSQxVM0qwtEhFSYKQjnQXAi8RMqth@waa04ZZCvRxr/@jPUD)

Comment: you can use `!` instead of `==0`

Comment: This is extra nice since it's vectorized, too!

Comment: I think you can get rid of the exterior brackets as well `!(8*scan()+1)^.5%%1`

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 5 bytes

```
t:Ysm
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@19iFVmc@/@/oQEA)

Explanation:

```
t       % Duplicate input
 :      % Range(1, input)
  Ys    % Cumulative sum. This will push the first *n* triangular numbers
    m   % ismember. Pushes true if the input is contained within the array we just pushed
```

Comment: I was going to post `t:Ys=a`. Forgot about `m` :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo I didn't know about `m` until I saw [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/121747/31716). Funny how the two answer are almost identical :D

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <strike>10</strike> 7 bytes

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to @Luke and @ETHproductions*

```
*8Ä ¬v1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@69lcbhF4dCaMsP//w0B)

#### Explanation:

```
*8Ä ¬v1
    ¬    // Square root of:
*8       //   Input * 8
  Ä      //   +1
     v1  // Return 1 if divisible by 1; Else, return 0
```

---

```
õ å+ øU
```

#### Explanation:

```
õ å+ øU
õ           // Create a range from [1...Input]
  å+        // Cumulative reduce by addition
     øU     // Does it contain the input?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///BWhcNLtRUO7wj9/183N4iLK9pQh8tYh8tMh8vQAIhNdbiMgCKmINocJGhqYgBiGhjqACkdLhOgnA6XuQ6XhQ6XJVAaqNYQqMwYKGVqEAsA)

Comment: The question asks for two constant distinct ouputs.

Comment: `*8Ä ¬u1 c` for 9B (outputs 0 if input is triangular, 1 otherwise)

Comment: @Luke You could change `u1 c` to `v1`, I believe (switching the outputs)

Comment: 7 bytes? Nice! Somehow missed this while posting my own, similar solution late last might. Let me know if you'd like me to delete it.

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 17 bytes

```
{$_∈[\+] 1..$_}
```

Just checks whether `$_`, the input to the function, is equal to any of the elements of the triangular addition reduction `(1, 1+2, ..., 1+2+...+$_)`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), <s>38</s> 22 bytes

*A lot of bytes saved thanks to Martin and Leo*

```
/ i \2*.2RE.h*-n/ o @
```

There is a trailing newline. Outputs `1` for triangular, `0` otherwise.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/alice#@6@vkKkQY6SlZxTkqpehpZunr5Cv4MD1/7@hKQA)

#### Explanation

This uses the same approach as my [CJam answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/122096/36398), only clumsier. In linearized form, the program becomes

```
i2*.2RE.h*-no@
```

where the `i` and `o` are actually in ordinal mode.

Consider input `21` as an example.

```
i         Input integer                       STACK: 21
2*        Multiply by 2                       STACK: 42
.         Duplicate                           STACK: 42, 42
2RE       Integer square root                 STACK: 42, 6
.         Duplicate                           STACK: 42, 6, 6
h         Increment                           STACK: 42, 6, 7
*         Multiply                            STACK: 42, 42
-         Subtract                            STACK: 0
n         Logical negation                    STACK: 1
o         Output integer                      STACK:
@         End program
```

Comment: My first Alice answer

Comment: I have a feeling this could be roughly halved with one of Martin's fancy control structures...

Comment: So do I ... :-)

Comment: My first Alice golf: [Same code, 23 bytes](https://tio.run/nexus/alice#@2@onx9jpKVnFORaxqXgkKlfoqKrlaFn8/@/oSkA "Alice – TIO Nexus")

Comment: A more "standard" layout for this kind of program would be [this](https://tio.run/nexus/alice#@2@on8@lEJPpoG@kpWcU5KqXoaWrUvL/v6EpAA). That said, you could get rid of the 1 on the stack, and simply output the logical negation of the subtraction (i.e. `...h*-no@`)

Comment: The simplest way to golf your current version by a lot is to move the `o` into the first line (simply write `...t/ o @`). That already shortens it to 25. Doing the same for the `i` saves one more byte. (Of course, Leo's suggestion is still a fair bit shorter than that.)

Comment: @MartinEnder Thanks! If only characters had a square shape... :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo You can get 18 by using Leo's layout.

Comment: @Nitrodon You should post that as your answer :-)

Comment: @MartinEnder I think I'll leave that to him, as it's a significant change

Comment: @Leo Thanks for the tips. I'm not changing the layout, as it's a significant change. Feel free to post it yourself!

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>7</s> 6 bytes

**EDIT**: Thanks to @Dennis: Saved a byte because I forgot about the increment operator

```
8*>t.ï
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fQsuuRO/w@v//zQA)

`n` is triangular if `sqrt(8n + 1)` is an integer

How it works

```
8* # multiply implicit input by 8
  > # add one
   t # sqrt
    .ï # is integer
```

Comment: Probably wasn't available yet at the time, but `t.ï` can be `Å²` these days, which is a builtin to check if a number is a square.

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 5 bytes

```
≥ℕ⟦+?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@/@oc@mjlqmP5i/Ttv//39AUAA)

### Explanation

```
≥ℕ⟦+?
≥ℕ     There is a number from 0 to {the input} inclusive
  ⟦    such that the range from 0 to that number
   +   has a sum
    ?  that equals the input
```

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b), 4 bytes

```
ÅTs¢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//cGtI8aFF//@bAQA)

Explanation:

```
ÅT     //push all triangle numbers <= (implicit) input
  s    //push input onto stack
   ¢   //count occurrences of input in triangle numbers (i.e. 1 if triangle, 0 if not)
```

I'm using 05AB1E (legacy) since it pre-dates this challenge, but it works in current 05AB1E as well

Comment: You can use 05AB1E rewrite for your answer as answers in languages newer than the challenge are now allowed.

Answer (score 4):

## [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/)’s type system, 91 bytes

```typescript
//@ts-ignore
type F<N,A=[],I=N["length"]>=N extends[...infer R,0]?F<R,[1,...R,...A],I>:A[I]
```

[Try it at the TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTACBcGcFoEsHMB2B7ATgUwLAChwE8AHdAAgDEAeAOQBoBBAXgG0BdagSXssYCIAbdRPHAALbswB8nYugAe4AQBNIjAHRrYiAGbpUxAErUADMwD8FA4wCM1NSoO3arNuIBctRm2Y5vuQiQAq6JDgAGzE9GTkjIZGsTHxEjggxCnEAHomOPhExIHBAJzhkdFxpfFxidjJqRlZfrlB4JaGRRQl5R1lRpXVKbXYQA)

This is a generic type `F` taking a unary number `N` as a tuple of N zeroes. I never would have expected a challenge like this to be under 100 bytes in TS types, but in this instance it’s quite doable. This is almost definitely ungolfable.

This works by creating the string `1101001000100001…`, which contains N ones separated by as many zeroes as there are already added ones, and indexing into this string with N.

Explanation of the code:

```typescript
//@ts-ignore - Suppress any type errors on the following line.
type F<
  N,            // N is a tuple type of 0s
  A=[],         // A becomes the string, starts as an empty list
  I=N["length"] // I is the original N which we use to index at the end
>=
  N extends[...infer R,0] // If a 0 fits in N, take the difference R (i.e. decrement)
    ?F<R,            // If that succeeded, recurse with N = R,
      [1,...R,...A], // A with 1 then R prepended,
    I>               // and I kept as it was.
  :A[I] // If it failed, N is 0, so index into A with the original number.
```

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, 30 Bytes

Prints 1 for true and nothing for false

```
<?=fmod(sqrt(8*$argn+1),2)==1;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#s7EvyCjgUkksSs@zNTOz5rK3@29jb5uWm5@iUVxYVKJhoQWW0zbU1DHStLU1tP7/HwA)

[fmod](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php)

## PHP, 37 Bytes

Prints 1 for true and nothing for false

```
<?=($x=sqrt($q=2*$argn)^0)*$x+$x==$q;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#s7EvyCjgUkksSs@zNTOz5rK3@29jb6uhUmFbXFhUoqFSaGukBZbVjDPQ1FKp0AbK2KoUWv//DwA)

Answer (score 3):

### Mathematica, 28 bytes

```
!Accumulate@Range@#~FreeQ~#&
```

Comment: I recommend replacing `7!` by `#`. First, it's shorter; more importantly, the current solution is not correct, as it artificially imposes a limit on the size of the input it works on.

Comment: OP says: "You may assume that the input is a positive integer under 10^6".But I like your idea and I will take it ,although mine gives the right result for every case using a list of 5040 elements but yours worst case needs a list of 999999 elements.Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Oops sorry, didn't see the OP's comment! Yes, there are some "perverse" incentives in code golfing: that 1-byte savings is more important in a code-golf question than all the efficiency in the world :)

Answer (score 3):

### Batch, 72 bytes

```
@set/aj=i=0
:l
@if %1% gtr %j% set/aj+=i+=1&goto l
@if %1==%j% echo 1
```

Outputs 1 on success, nothing on failure. Works for zero too, although not requested by the question for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES7), <s>19</s> 18 bytes

From [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/119011/58974) to a [related question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/118980/58974).

Outputs `false` for triangular numbers or `true` for non-triangular, as permitted by the OP.

```
n=>(8*n+1)**.5%1>0
```

---

### Try It

```js
f=
n=>(8*n+1)**.5%1>0
oninput=_=>o.innerText=f(+i.value)
```

```html
<input id=i type=number><pre id=o>
```

Comment: I think you could save a byte with `n=>(8*n+1)**.5%1>0` (which would reverse the outputs)

Comment: @ETHproductions: OK, as long as you're allowing it. Is doing so normally permitted, though?

Comment: It qualifies as "two constant, distinct outputs", so yes. Other decision-problem challenges may require truthy/falsy though.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 18 bytes

```
n->issquare(8*n+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pari-gp#LY5BC8IwDIX/Sthp1Q6adF2bg/sj4mEHBwMpc9ODv36@iC0l6cd7L5npQkftxmXfn@9pu7flVM/sjmldH5@2UjfSui31hbaxT0NzW53zdGVP0dPgiQNe8iQgyWo2mPpgbTAYEvo8iPGips0sCW7OkQdQEWG2wID7qzlLMCesqKpFFVw89aDweyrASABlJEQxNRRqNlujT7ZHZC3FxuaoZg38D7Rzc8cX)

---

There is a built-in to test if a number is a polygonal number, but it is one byte longer.

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 19 bytes

```
n->ispolygonal(n,3)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pari-gp#LY6xCsMwDER/RWSKwQFLjmNraH6kdMiSEgiOabvk69NTqY2R/Lg7aaUbXXWYt3c79vN51GXvq4/uWlrbz77SMFN7bfWDtrNPR2tfnfN0Z0/R0@SJA17yJCDJajaYxmBtMBgS@jyJ8aKmzSwJbs6RJ1ARYbbAgPurOUswJ6yoqkUVXDyNoPB7KsBIAGUkRDE1FGo2W2NMtkdkLcXG5qhmDfwPtPNw1xc)

Answer (score 3):

## Excel, <s>31</s> 22 bytes

9 bytes saved thanks to Octopus

Outputs `TRUE` for triangular numbers.  Else `FALSE`. Checks if `8*n+1` is a perfect square.

```
=MOD(SQRT(8*B1+1),1)=0
```

Comment: `=MOD(SQRT(8*A1+1),1)=0` saves a few bytes

Answer (score 3):

## Python - 52 bytes

***Note:*** *I know that the other two Python answers are much shorter, but this is the old-school way, more of a by-hand algorithm*

```
n=input();i=s=0
while s<n:s=(i*i+i)/2;i+=1
print s>n
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Alchemist](https://github.com/bforte/Alchemist), 80 bytes

```
_->In_n+s
f+b->f+a
f+0b->a
0f+n+a->b
0f+0a+n->n+f
0n+a+s->Out_n
0n+0a+s->Out_"1"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcgxDoAgDEDRnWOwNk3q4tjdySOQohJJtJiA17fi4vb@l2PZtzPXZhaQJw0K1SWIyAmkg7rEUQIFQY6fSECRFZKjPqEiz3cL@hX96QdvNj7larloNVxf)

[Test cases](https://tio.run/##TY47C8IwFIVn8ysuIdJKiEaki4/sTjroJpQ0D1rQG23qpP722CIUt@8cOI9KxzoZ3W23mUObgQITrJubFlMp1B5L5JF4Xgnlue5B9qSJ9By5FqoaSGqOQiH3RPYmj0Idnl2Jg5KjpEua@gHiQwsIDQLLo3sAW842YAOZHM6n4/m0Y7kzdQCG8IZFuHcLfTW1uzXxj8aHMzK5tw12Huh0ZQGm8YJ0yFL2@vWtBXwosQFdSkXxBQ)

Subtracts increasing numbers from the input until it reaches 0, and checks if the counter is zero.

Answer (score 2):

## TI-BASIC, <s>10</s> 7 bytes

*-3 thanks to [@lirtosiast](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/39328/lirtosiast)*

```
:not(fPart(√(8Ans+1
```

Takes input on `X`. Checks if `√(8X+1)` is a whole number

Comment: Why not `not(fPart(√(8Ans+1`?

Comment: @lirtosiast That'll work, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Fourier](https://github.com/beta-decay/Fourier), 26 bytes

```
I~X1(&N^*N/2{X}{1~O}N=X)Oo
```

[**Try it online!**](https://beta-decay.github.io/editor/?code=SX5YMSgmTl4qTi8ye1h9ezF-T31OPVgpT28)

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 6 bytes

```apl
⊢∊+\∘⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///3/FR24RHXYsedXRpxzzqmPGod/P//4/aJmoAxXQcNQ@tAAoYGgAA)

#### Explanation

```apl
⊢∊+\∘⍳
      ⍳                 Creates a range from 1 to the right_argument
  +\                    Cumulative sum of this range; 1 1+2 1+2+3 .. 1+2+..+n. These are the triangular numbers
⊢∊                      Does the right argument belong to this list of integers in this cumulative sum
```

Outputs `0` for false and `1` for true.

Answer (score 2):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 12 bytes

```
I8*P12,X1%zh
```

6 bytes golfed off, courtesy of JoKing! A codebreakdown will be coming soon!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/39NCK8DQSCfCULUKyDMGAA)

First version, 18 bytes

```
I8*P12,X1}:S(-Zh0h
```

I found a pretty simple formula for solving this, which helped golf this, since we are only looking to see if the number *is* triangular, rather than calculate it.

[Link to wiki where I found the formula!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number)

[image: Triangular Number Formula]

**Code Breakdown!**

```
I8*P              //Multiply the output by eight
    12,X          //Get the square root
        1}        //Push a value for truthy output and put it on the bottom
          :S(-    //Check to see if it is a perfect squareroot, no floating point
              Zh0h//If the difference is zero(perfect squareroot) output truthy, otherwise, push a falsey and output!
```

There is a way to remove 2 bytes, but it outputs the input plus one for truthy, which I don't think is to the specification of *"You must pick two constant, distinct outputs to distinguish the two categories"*.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/39NCK8DQSCfCsNYqWEM3KsMAKGYMAA)

Comment: You can replace `1}:S(-Zh0h` with `1%zh`

Comment: A tip: You don't need to use conditionals like `?ZqQ` for value checking. Just transform the values directly into 1 or 0 using comparison operators

Comment: @JoKing Thank you very much, I have made the changes and it has popped off 6 bytes!

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <s>45</s> <s>40</s> 39 bytes

```python
lambda n:0in[n:=n+~i for i in range(n)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPqfpmCrEPM/JzE3KSVRIc/KIDMvOs/KNk@7LlMhLb9IIVMhM0@hKDEvPVUjTzP2P0goDyFkqGNoYKBpxaWgUFCUmVeikaZUnVeroGunUJ0GVF6rpPkfAA), which is a golf of this more standard

```python
lambda n,t=0:n in[t:=t+i for i in range(n+1)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcixCoMwFAXQvV9xcUqwQqRLCcQfUYeITRuo1xDeIuK3Rzt1PCdt8ln5eKZcAhyG8vXLNHvwLs5YIrIX66SOCGtGvIzs@X4p1q0eyy/5z9YYbW9AypGiQrXzQNNhD4r6qHQ5AQ) Not a Python winner but it showcases the `:=` walrus operator in a scenario where it could *actually* be used in the real world! Hehe

Comment: A bit shorter counting downwards: [TIO](https://tio.run/##RcgxCoQwFAXA3lM8rBJEiNhIQC@iFll2ox/0GUKaRTx7xMopJ/zTerDtQswePaa8uf3zdaA1wpG2Zy3wR4RAiOi4/BSrRs/5Sb7ZGKNtAYQoTMqXJy/UA06vqK9S5xs "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online")

Comment: @xnor oh wow, that is really clever

Comment: [-1](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPqfpmCrEPM/JzE3KSVRIc/KIDMvOs/KNk@7LlMhLb9IIVMhM0@hKDEvPVUjTzP2P0goDyFkqGNoYKBpxaWgUFCUmVeikaZUnVeroGunUJ0GVF6rpPkfAA) because we don't need to handle zero.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 26 bytes

```c
f(n){fmod(sqrt(8*n+1),1);}
```

Outputs zero for truthy and nonzero for falsy.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PZDbTsQgEIbveQpCsglYNgI9AFs33vkE3q29aNrtStKDttVEm766daYxDiH/8DH/cKiOt6ratob3Ymm6oebT@zhzd9dHWkgt8nUL/Uy7MvT8cwi1IAuhEAjn6lLQ875ciJYkliSTRCuYqSQGSIpqEaaJwlQhVCnkNjPIncdaq00Kbm1jnQE1xmiNDRWMXa01Cp1gBfXeeQ/cSJIABb8kDjB0AKqhQ2ywGio82vAaSYr3iLV3Do@1sUer0n8NMeT@lDUnuzbDyPGVgZ6pykEe6BS@r0PD50rc/6cXVQjYjSKxuzDeRvA1nB3qEz1MXy89k/hXoZB0d4RC0EfKnsp2YvRE2fP4Mb8ykZN1@6matrxN27HtfgE)

Comment: Why the downvote? If it's about the output format, I haven't gotten a response back from the OP on that.

Comment: Maybe the unspecified flags?

Answer (score 2):

## [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents), 4 bytes

```
?Z+$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/3z5KW@X/fyNDAA)

cQuents is literally made for these questions.

```
?    # Query (Outputs if the input is in the sequence)
 Z   # Previous term of the sequencd
  +$ # Plus the index (starts from 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 4 bytes

```
±£∫N
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9DGQ4sfdaz2@///vyUYAAA)

Since it reqiures a constant truthy value, `±`(sign) is used.

Answer (score 2):

## Regex (ECMAScript), 37 bytes

**Warning:** Despite this regex's small size, it contains a **major spoiler**. I highly recommend learning how to solve unary mathematical problems in ECMAScript regex by figuring out the initial mathematical insights independently. It's been a fascinating journey for me, and I don't want to spoil it for anybody who might potentially want to try it themselves, especially those with an interest in number theory. [See this earlier post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/178889/17216) for a list of consecutively spoiler-tagged recommended problems to solve one by one.

So **do not read any further if you don't want some advanced unary regex magic spoiled for you**. If you do want to take a shot at figuring out this magic yourself, I highly recommend starting by solving some problems in ECMAScript regex as outlined in that post linked above.

This is the simplest natural number unary [decision-function](/questions/tagged/decision-function) that, in order to be implemented in ECMAScript regex, absolutely requires an algorithm for generalized multiplication. This is in contrast to matching perfect squares and other powers, which can be done by [dividing out prime factors individually](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19262/match-strings-whose-length-is-a-fourth-power/21951#21951) (although the best golf is not achieved that way). Generalized multiplication can be implemented by prime factorization, and I did so on my initial try, but it [takes 600+ bytes](https://github.com/Davidebyzero/RegexGolf/blob/master/regex%20for%20matching%20multiplication%20-%20factoring%20method.txt).

> Remarkably, generalized multiplication can be implemented quite concisely in ECMAScript regex using the Chinese remainder theorem. The algorithm is discussed in my [abundant numbers answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/110708/an-abundance-of-integers/178952#178952).

[teukon posed the Triangular Numbers puzzle in 2014](https://gist.github.com/Davidebyzero/9090628#gistcomment-1183455), after we had both figured out the best algorithm for generalized multiplication. I was not able to beat his golf on this problem; he managed to get it down to [37 bytes](https://gist.github.com/Davidebyzero/9090628#gistcomment-1184961), but I was only able to get it down to [48 bytes](https://gist.github.com/Davidebyzero/9090628#gistcomment-1184733). He's unlikely to ever create an account on CGCC, and I haven't been able to even get in contact with him since 2014. I feel this very elegant regex belongs on CGCC, though, and the ideas behind it were a joint effort between us, so I'm posting on his behalf:

```
^((((x*)x?)\3)x)(?=\4(\1*)\2*$)\1*$\5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/BTsJAFEV/BRsC7xVbKEUXjAMrF2xY6NJqMoFH@3SYTmYGqAjfXsvCxLu6ybnJzflUR@U3jm1IvOUtuX1tvui7ddLQqfdC5XNjAc5yMY7bD@jSxNgsscixQVjKYgZFFmMxjfvYlX7x0MbjM6ahfg2OTQmYes0bgsf7ZIYovJyIU8WaALR0pLaaDQHinTQHrfGnlDr1VnOAYTJEwTsAI8tUkylDhYvp5cJ@rdbA0irnaWUClG@Td8Q/QP@BWWTLbH7DGCpXn6KVOSrN255TpqR5LxppsasdCH6SJHg0wu4waqLUkSUVgDHdq7CpwCH@@MHAdkoBbhaZsIfgg@sm4nptsyTL8/wX)

```
^                  # N = input number
(                  # \1 = n*2-1 or n*2+1
    (              # \2 = \1-1
        (          # \3 = n-1 or n
            (x*)   # \4 = n-1
            x?
        )
        \3
    )
    x
)
(?=
    \4(\1*)\2*$    # iff \1+\4*\1 == N, then the first match here must result in \5 == 0
)
\1*$\5             # test for divisibility by \1 and for \5 == 0 simultaneously
```

Including zero in the "truthy" category only costs 1 byte (bringing it to **38 bytes**), using ECMAScript NPCG (non-participating/unset capture group) behavior:

```
^((((x*)x?)\3)x)?(?=\4(\1*)\2*$)\1*$\5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY89b8IwFEX/Co0QvBeaQAjtgGsydWBhKGPTShY8HLfGsWwDKR@/PQ1Dpd7pSudKV@dLHIXfOGVD4q3aktvX5pt@WscNnXpvJF8bC3Dmi3HcfkKXJsamwDLHBgsoeDmDMouxnMZ97Eq/fGrj8RnTUK@DU0YCpl6rDcHzYzJDZJ5P2KlSmgA0dyS2WhkCxAduDlrjRXKdeqtVgGEyRKZ2AIbLVJORocLF9HpVfiVWoLgVztPSBJDvkw/EP0D/gVlkRTa/YwyVq0/R0hyFVtueE0bSvBeNNNvVDph64cTUaITdYdREqSNLIoDCdC/CpgKHePGDge2UAtwtMmYPwQfXTdjt1k6SLM/zXw)

Doing so with NPCG-independent behavior costs 3 bytes, bringing it to **40 bytes**:

```
^((((x*)x?)\3)x)(?=\4(\1*)\2*$)\1*$\5|^$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY89b8IwFEX/Co0ieC80gRDaAdcwdWBhaMemSBY8HLfGsWwDKR@/PQ1Dpd7pSudKV@dLHIXfOGVD6q3aktvX5pt@WscNnXpvJF8bC3Dm81HSrqFLk2CzwLLABmHByymUeYLlJImxK3H5dF3HbTI6Yxbq9@CUkYCZ12pD8PyYThGZ52N2qpQmAM0dia1WhgDxgZuD1niRXGfeahVgkA6QqR2A4TLTZGSocD65XpVfiRUoboXztDQB5Mf4E/EP0H9g5vkin90xhsrVp2hpjkKrbc8JI2nWi4aa7WoHTL1wYmo4xO4waqLMkSURQGG2F2FTgUO8@H7fdkoB7hY5s4fgg@sm7HZrx2leFMUv)

### Returning the triangular root

**48 bytes** with zero-handling, based on the 38 byte true/false version:

```
^(?=((((x*)x?)\3)x)?(?=\4(\1*)\2*$)\1*$\5)x?\3\4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY@/bsIwGMRfJY0Q@b6kCYTQDrgmUwcWhnZsWskCk7h1HMs2kPJn5QH6iH2RNAxIvel0v@HuPtmO2ZUR2sVWizU3daO@@HdnqOJ774WXz60GOND5KOw@IKfQqw2xzbHIsMW8j4opFGmIxSQcYG8GxUOPi6yYduHogIlrXp0RqgRMrBQrDo/38RSRWDom@0pIDiCp4WwtheKAeEfVVko8llQmVkvhIIgDJGIDoGiZSK5KV@F8cjoJu2RLEFQzY/lCOSjfxu@IN8D/AzVP83R2xegq0@z9hdoxKdaeYarkM8@PJNk0Boh4opyIKMK@sKZ@6yeGa84cCExq5lYVGMSjHQ51f8rB9UdK9NZZZ0BEgfd7@fGCqO6X3KaS87kbx2mWZX8)

**46 bytes** without zero-handling, based on the 37 byte true/false version:

```
^(?=((((x*)x?)\3)x)(?=\4(\1*)\2*$)\1*$\5)x\3\4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY@/TsMwGMRfJURV830JSZumMNS4nRi6dIARg2S1bmJwHMt229A/Kw/AI/IiIR2QuOl0v@Hu3vmeu7WVxqfOyI2wdaM/xGdnqRaH4EmUj60BONL5KO7eYEGhVxtju0BWYIt9wqbA8hjZJB5gbwbsDltWsGkXj46Y@ebZW6lLwMwpuRZwf5tOEYmjY3KopBIAilrBN0pqAYg3VO@UwlNJVeaMkh6iNEIitwCalpkSuvQVzifns3QrvgJJDbdOLLWH8mX8ivgHxH@g5/kin10x@so2h3Cp91zJTWC5LsUsCBNFto0FIh@oIDJJsC@sadiGmRVGcA8Ss5r7dQUW8eSGQ9Of8nD9kROz885bkEkU/Hx9B1FS90v@ppLLpcvTvCiKXw)

I haven't tried golfing this down yet. There may be specific golf optimizations for returning the triangular root.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

All of the following programs work:

```
ÅTθQ
ÅTI¢
ÅTIå
ÅTs¢
ÅTså
ÅT¹¢
ÅT¹å
```

[Try](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cGvIuR2B//8bG5ibGxkAAA) [every](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cGuI56FF//8bG5ibGxkAAA) [single](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cGuI5@Gl//8bG5ibGxkAAA) [one](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cGtI8aFF//8bG5ibGxkAAA) [of](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cGtI8eGl//8bG5ibGxkAAA) [these](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cGvIoZ2HFv3/b2xgbm5kAAA) [programs](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cGvIoZ2Hl/7/b2xgbm5kAAA) [online!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ)

`ÅT` is all triangular numbers \$≤\$ implicit input, `θ` is last element (`a[-1]`), `Q` is equality (`a==b`), `I` and `¹` are input (`input()`), `¢` is occurrences (`a.count(b)`), and `å` is membership (`b in a`).

Answer (score 2):

## [Fourier](https://github.com/beta-decay/Fourier), 24 bytes

```
I~_(~#^*#/2{_}{1~$}#^)$o
```

Based on my [other answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242602/108170)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svLcpMLfr/37MuXqNOOU5LWd@oOr622rBOpVY5TlMl//9/czMjMwA)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 105 bytes

```
import math
n=int(input(""))
if float(math.sqrt(8*n+1)).is_integer():
    print("y")
else:
    print("n")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYsxCoAwDEX3nqJkShQE6SKCZxGHqgGb1jYOnr7q6B/fez/dukdxtXJIMasNi@5GJhZFlnQpAhAZXu16xEXx0105s@LQSNsTdVzmN/abz0ijse9S/t5wAxl/FP@DAlSrewA)

Comment: Your answer can be a function, so it can be `lambda n:float(math.sqrt(8*n+1)).is_integer();import math`. And `math.sqrt` can be replaced with `**0.5`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 27 bytes

```
f(n)=0^{mod((8n+1)^{.5},1)}
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gzbxiemnsg)

Answer (score 2):

## TI-BASIC (TI-83/84) , <strike>28 26</strike>  10 bytes

saved 2 bytes by using a different method

count was way off

`:fPart(√(8Ans+1))=0`

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf StackExchange, and nice first answer! I don't know TI-BASIC, but it seems that [it has a special way to count bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1541/9288), so your answer might be shorter than 28 bytes.

Comment: Taking the input from a predefined variable is not allowed, [but Ans is allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9353)

Comment: See the other [ti-basic answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/122128)

Answer (score 2):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 18 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/9/eQstQO6UsRSvaILbY09azquD/f0tLC0tLQwA)

```
?8*1+dvd*[0]sI=Izp
```

Prints 1 if triangular, 0 if not.

### Explanation:

```
?       get input (call it x)
8*1+    let y = 8 * x + 1
d       duplicate
vd*     square root, then square (dc's sqrt has integer precision)
[0]sI=I if y == sqrt(y)^2, leave 0 on stack, otherwise leave nothing
zp      print stack depth
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Could you provide a link that shows the program on multiple inputs, like tio.run/#dc?

Comment: I added a tio link, but the program only takes one value at a time.

Answer (score 1):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 62 bytes

```
(([(({}))])<>){(({}())<>{}({})){(<><>)}{}<>}<>([[]]()()()<>{})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X0MjWkOjulZTM1bTxk6zGsTW0AQygRRItFrDxg4oXltda2MHRBrR0bGxGpogCFKi@f@/kSEA)

#### Explanation

Effectively, this code starts with n and subtracts 1, 2, 3, ... n.  If an intermediate result is 0, this is marked by decreasing the size of the left stack.

```
   (({}))                         duplicate input n
 ([      ])                       push -n as accumulator
(          <>)                    push -n on other stack as counter

{                            }    while counter is nonzero
  ({}())                          increment counter
        <>{}                      add to accumulator
            ({})                  add stored copy of n (effectively, this adds a counter that starts at 1 instead of -n)
 (              )                 push as new accumulator value
                 {(<><>)}{}       If accumulator is zero, shrink the stack by one
                           <>     switch back to right stack

<>                                move to left stack
   [[]]()()()                     3 minus height of left stack (which is 2 if n is triangular and 3 otherwise)
             <>{}                 move back to right stack and pop zero from loop
  (              )                push answer
```

Comment: I ctrl-F'd for "><>"... Oh, there's already- no wait, that's Brain-Flak?

Answer (score 1):

### [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>30</s> 28 bytes

<sup>-2 bytes thanks to lanlock4</sup>

Assumes input is on the stack. Outputs either a `1` or `0`.

```
0v
1<~v!?(}:{:,2*+1::+
n={<;
```

This was fun. I'm new to ><>, and I'd welcome any suggestions for golfing.

This starts with `n=1`, then continually increments `n` while `n(n-1)/2` is less than the input number. Once the loop terminates, it prints `1` if `n(n-1)/2` is equal to the input number, `0` otherwise.

Comment: If you move the `+1` to the left of the `<` on the second line and start at `n=0` instead of `n=1`, you can get rid of both of the spaces, [like this](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/36CMy9CmrkzRXqPWqtpKx0hL29DKSpsrz7baxvr///@6ZQqGBgA).

Answer (score 1):

## 2Col, 8 bytes [non-competing]

```
*8
+1
Sq
```

Try it on [2Collide](https://gunnerwolf.github.io/2col/index.html?code=KjgKKzEKU3E)

Braingolf got boring so now I'm making a new language. Link leads to the current 2Col interpreter in TIO, with the above code already inserted. 3rd argument is input.

2Col is a language where each line is a 2 character expression of some form.
It's what I like to call an "Accumulator-based" language. It works like Stack-based languages, except the "stack" can only contain a single item.

#### Explanation:

```
        Implicit input to Cell
*8      Multiply Cell by 8
+1      Add 1 to Cell
Sq      Return true if Cell is square number
        Implicit: Print final line's return value
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, 45 bytes

```c
a,i;f(n){while(i<=n&&(a=i*i+i++!=2*n));a=!a;}
```

[Try it online.](https://cg5.tutorialspoint.com/share/569/lO5jZvpr)

**Explanation:**

```c
a,i; - data definition with no type or storage class is allowed in C (gives a warning). Doesn't work in C++ though.
f(n) - This behavior(parameter without type - by default assigned an integer type) is to provide backwards compatibility with older K&R version of C.
while() - loop is self explanatory
a=!a; - the return value of the function should be in "eax" register, but it is often also used as scratch register by calee. So we do a negation operation to store the answer in the eax which gets returned.
```

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, 10

```
ri8*)_mQ%!
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=ri8*)_mQ%25!&input=55)

It checks if 8*n+1 is divisible by its integer square root.

Comment: Interesting variant of the `8*n+1` method. In general this divisibility check tells if a number is of the form `k^2`, `k^2+k` or `k^2+2*k`, but a number of the form `8*n+1` can only be the first case.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 5 bytes

```
←Đř△∈
```

Explanation:

```
←                 get input
 Đ                duplicate input (on stack twice)
  ř               push [1,...,input] onto stack
   △              calculate the kth triangle number for each element k in the array
    ∈             check if input is in array of triangle numbers
```

Longer but faster way, 9 bytes

```
←Đ2*√⌈ř△∈
```

Explanation:

```
←                     get input
 Đ                    duplicate input (on stack twice)
  2*                  double input
    √⌈                ceiling of the square root
      ř               push [1,...,value from previous step] onto stack
       △              calculate the kth triangle number for each element k in the array
        ∈             check if input is in array of triangle numbers
```

Answer (score 1):

## APL(NARS) 12 chars, 24 bytes

```
{0=1∣√1+8×⍵}
```

It is done seen(copy) some other solution...
it seems {1∣⍵} it is 0 when ⍵ is one int decimal with 0 digits afther the "."
test:

```
  f←{0=1∣√1+8×⍵}
  {⍞←{1=f ⍵:' ',⍵⋄⍬}⍵⋄⍬}¨0..200
 0  1  3  6  10  15  21  28  36  45  55  66  78  91  105  120  136  153  171  190
```

but i remember i wrote the solution to this a little +long, some time ago...

Answer (score 1):

## [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents), 4 bytes

```
?Z+$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/3z5KW@X/fzMA)

### Explanation

```
?Z+$
        Given input n,
?       Mode query: output true if n is in sequence, false if n is not in sequence
        Each term in the sequence equals
 Z      Previous term
  +                   +
   $                    current index (1-indexed)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 36 bytes

```powershell
for(;$args-gt$s){$s+=++$i}$s-in$args
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZPdasMwDIXv8xSmaCMhDdhOHMcbhb3JKJvTBULa2SkbZHn2zLh/RLKv9Ek6PhL4dPyxzn/Zvl@gZTs2Le3Rpa@wdwdfHEbw2QQ@3@U5dDP4ohtiZpmT5C1NWDjbVGwZjO5ss2tcorhGseAYKAQkllSkQhNVVXFSxIkQV7hK15JoNYZ40kIqPJnQpahxs5RSCLITHi6FWktOHAaLGBrTGPNov70UQLvv/b2swkBhoDFoMDAYxFnWpMakJFbimldEGoKUIgYrpam6MA3xKRpdGjowF5ftrWeK50Ez9see2BSzMARuf0/2Y7Sf4QPA@wU768/9GMBz@BcwRLiB9MoL@31vyl5CnnX@1rNJ5uUf)

This script is 6 bytes longer than the [briantist's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/122298/80745). The script works with any `[long]` (except for 0) and calculates only what is needed.

Answer (score 1):

## [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), <s>65</s> 60 bytes

```
(d T(q((N I)(i(l N 0)0(a(e N 0)(T(s N I)(a I 1)
(q((N)(T N 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcoxDoAgEETR3lNMOXRs4SFsTEy8wBotSFBQaDg9buh@8n4NT4uh5N55YudLrlgcAyNWeOepvEZxZ8EwxQJxk/3b@I0MpDMmPRHD8enXJt6abZCaIHP/AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 24 bytes

```scala
n=>math.sqrt(8*n+1)%1==0
```

Same approach as taken by many others here: check whether \$\sqrt{8n+1}\$ is an integer (via fractional modulo)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVDNTgIxEL7zFCPRZFcnpNNlf2qyGPXkxQu@QFm6gildaIvBEJ59HcBEiZ2k7Uzm@5kJjba672Yfponw5pfavW@t9q/b1cx4MLto3DzA43oN@8EAYG5aaO/hxUWoJ/DUddZoB3Xv6slKx8UobHxMqlt3R@kN1bXoAT61hei3cfH1rIMJUMPUbBLCDAskgZSjJMz5LjnPx4I/ggsiF1gWkmuV4p6SZJ4hlRkVBUopiZhBcByfspSCEQwRqFSlFKWDs3CrbbjQlThGZsMKFTIFFZhJhqJUzMAuxjnbyEhVFQuXmeJuQWfe40mPS1j7pYvWJWF4nguak0DTec9bfIDr/Z95R23ntbVJmx6G6QX45O0/9urX88jsliGGH@yh/wY)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
ɾ¦c
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLJvsKmYyIsIiIsIjI3NiJd) or [Try a Test Suite Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJhIiwixpsiLCLJvsKmYyIsIlwiYCUgLT4gJWAkJTtcXFxuaiIsIjFcbjNcbjZcbjEwXG4xNVxuMjFcbjU1XG4yNzZcbjJcbjRcbjVcbjdcbjhcbjlcbjExXG4xNlxuMzJcbjUwXG4yOTAiXQ==)

Can be [2 bytes](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJSIiwiIiwiwqZjIiwiIiwiMTAiXQ==) with the `R` flag.

The power of automatically swapping arguments based on types.

### Explained

```
ɾ¦c
ɾ    # The range [1..n]
 ¦  # Cumulative sums of that - this creates a list of the first n triangular numbers, which is guaranteed to include at least one number bigger than the input. 
  c # is the input in that list? The arguments popped are [input, triangles] but Vyxal is smart enough to realise that because a list will never be in a number, it can swap the arguments and perform the membership test.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata) + `-e`, 4 bytes

```
8*→√
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY47DsJADET7OQVKiYhke7MfnwVRAAoNAgrCFRA1JRRQgETBhWg5CRMFr7TeHb3x-PratuvdZt7N39Oq3lSTUVW31ez-PHSrurzK-Hs8f0-Xx36x3P_F--emCEhQgUaYIvLO_MdG-BAKEgU5GbXiZLJaDNAcNCWYmSonCE_fcjahgxaBe3FXGBrQhQIHUU0IRgTmJJnWRMYF9VIYkIOTFh38fQ17_gA)

```
8*→√
8*    Multiply the input by 8
  →   Increment
   √  Check if it's a perfect square
```

---

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata) + `-e`, 4 bytes

```
R∫$Ĩ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY0xCsJAFET7OYUsli78_3f_ZvcatiIYJTYSLZLcwTvYpFAM6DG8hK0n8YM2w8xjmLlMx-Zwauu-fq6cb91i5nzj1uNt6Pc-35ef82P-mq7ddtf92fjeMAISmMAKYahpZVkjmSEDpIQqibFcrFOxaIAgwjwyCpjBCUGsCilkE4qoNhK45Pw7-gI)

```
R∫$Ĩ
R     Range from 1 to input
 ∫    Cumulative sum
  $Ĩ  Check if it contains the input
```

Answer (score 1):

## R (4.1+), 20 bytes

R has a vectorized `cumsum()`, which can come in handy for time series data.

```r
\(x)x%in%cumsum(1:x)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhZbYjQqNCtUM_NUk0tzi0tzNQytKjQhUqvTNAwNNLmApCFUZMECCA0A)

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 27 bytes

This is my first time using Haskell rather than SML (I couldn't find a scan function), so I don't know if this is a valid answer, but it is a valid function in the interpreter.

```
\x->elem x(scanl(+)0[1..x])
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 14 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=0_8_0__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-KXv-KBv-KCmeKGp-KGpeKIoOKEguKnu-KWs-KHoeKKouKHjOKZrcKk4ouv4o2J4o2P4o2W4oqa4oqb4oqd4pe04pew4pah4ouV4omN4oqf4oqC4oqP4oqh4oav4piH4oaZ4oaY4oa74per4pa94oyV4oiK4oqX4oin4oi14omh4oqe4oqg4o2l4oqV4oqc4oqQ4ouF4oqZ4oipwrDijIXijZziioPiqr7iipPii5TijaLirJrijaPijaTihqzihqvimoLOt8-Az4TiiJ7iuK7ihpAiCgojIEFsbCBjaGFyYWN0ZXJzIFVpdWEgdXNlcyBmb3IgcHJldHR5LXByaW50aW5nLgojIENhbiBiZSByZW1vdmVkIGlmIG5lY2Vzc2FyeS4KCkRSQVdJTkcg4oaQICLila3ilIDilbfila_in6bin6fijJzijJ_ilZPilZ_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-KHoTPil4viiKkow7cyNSnih6EyNDDih6E4MCIKIyBFbmNvZGUgdG8gYSAuc2JjcyBmaWxlOgojICAgRW5jb2RlVUEgUGF0aFVBCiMgRGVjb2RlIGEgLnNiY3MgZmlsZToKIyAgIERlY29kZVNCQ1MgUGF0aFNCQ1MK)</sup>

Outputs 0 for `false` and 1 for `true`. Uses the "8n+1 is Perfect Square" method.

```
&p=⌊.√+1×8⋕&sc
```

[Try it online!](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=0_8_0__JnA94oyKLuKImisxw5c44ouVJnNjCg==)

### Explanation

```
&p=⌊.√+1×8⋕&sc
           &sc # Read line from stdin
          ⋕    # Parse string as number
      +1×8     # Multiply by 8, then add 1
     √         # Square root
    .          # Duplicate
   ⌊           # Floor
  =            # Compare for equality
&p             # Print with newline
```

Answer (score 1):

## Uiua, 6 bytes

```
∊:\+⇡.
```

[Try it](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0__SXNUcmlhbmd1bGFyIOKGkCDiiIo6XCvih6EuCgrilr3iiaFJc1RyaWFuZ3VsYXIu4oehMTAwMAo=)

Is the input a member of taking the cumulative sums of the range of 0 to the input?

Answer (score 0):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), <s>21</s> 19 bytes

```
[:|p=p+a~p=b|_x1}?0
```

Explanation

```
[ |     FOR a = 1 to
 :        b (read from the cmd line)
p=p+a   increment p by a (+1, +2, ...) (p is 0 at QBIC start)
~p=b|   IF p == b ; we've hit a triangular number!
_x1     THEN QUIT, printing 1
}       Close the IF and the FOR
?0      We didn't quit early, so print 0
```

Comment: The `8x+1` trick is actually longer: `b=sqr(8*:+1)?b=int(b)`

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 54 bytes

```
#(and(some #{%}(reductions +(rest(range(max % 3)))))1)
```

I wish various truthy values were allowed so I didn't need to coerce them all to `1` with a penalty of 6 bytes.

Without caring about edge cases of 0 or 1, and allowing any truthy value this would have been just 35 bytes:

```
#(some #{%}(reductions +(range %)))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>11</s> <s>9</s> 7 bytes

Port of [my JS answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/122102/58974). Outputs `1` for triangular numbers or `0` otherwise.

```
*8Ä ¬v1
```

[Try it online](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.4&code=KjjEIKx2MQ==&input=MTU0MA==)

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 47 bytes

```c
a,i;f(n){for(a=i=0;i++<n+3;)a|=i*i==8*n+1;a=a;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#dZCxDsIwDERn@IxKSEnToWkoJDL5ExZLKJIHDKq6lX57oCPi8PjOZ/tcuRMqRu1SHpPhLLknce6iLpDlV5ZWco6tOk@cmdZ6Z1HDdtnvnpPoXExzuF216Yrx1tIvDZCeIPU9xiPEA1444u6UYkrfjo8A50L/ES@D9AxpxHfhyDibx38Lw5/IW23SWt8)

Undefined behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, <s>58</s> <s>48</s> 23 bytes

```
n->Math.sqrt(8*n+1)%1>0
```

Port of [*@xnor*'s amazing Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/122092/52210).

-25 bytes by using a Java 8 lambda instead of Java 7 method (and `Math.sqrt(...)` instead of `Math.pow(...,.5)`).

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##jVRBboMwELznFXupBK2CvAZjW1Hzg@SSY9WDQ0hLSgwFJ1JV5e3UaXNtp1iyBDPeWe/scnBnN@/62h92b1PVunGklWv854yo8aEe9q6qaX19Jdp2XVs7T1USIfLpIn69zCjuY3ChqWhNnh5p8vPlyoXXbHwfQmLu/QOnd7wU02IWqf1p20bq7cS5a3Z0jILJJgyNf3l6Jpf@qG0@xlAfs@4Usj5CofWJz6qE02/dX/Ec4CXAWSCCAgSJUlQwgoZZqkLAIAImIhSKoksJczEW1kSzVMgZ1jmXSExKyQx7QMSFSVpLASsUS4RI1hpr/5IDVwLhC5Qjqj3ADboe8g1VmpGpuYQ2oLaw0Ek4dYWCY5ezNQaOg84t9Ezwf/rq@qS3/@xl@gI)

Comment: Why Math.pow instead of Math.sqrt?

Answer (score 0):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), 6 bytes

```
Γ)
```

Explanation:

```
       Inclusive range; [1 .. input]
 Γ      For each...
         Inclusive range; [1 .. element]
         Sum
    )   End for each
       Check that the input is in the list
```

[Try it!](http://178.62.56.56:80/neim?code=%F0%9D%90%88%CE%93%F0%9D%90%88%F0%9D%90%AC)%F0%9D%95%9A&input=1)

Answer (score 0):

## VB.NET, 65

```
Sub T(n,j)
j=Math.Sqrt(8*n+1)
Console.Write(CInt(j)=j)
End Sub
```

Like other answers, determines if `8n + 1` is an integer or not.

Explanation:

```
Sub T(n,j)                     ' start the method, use n as the triangle number to check
                               ' declare j here as well for use later, saving 4 bytes over a "dim j" call

j=Math.Sqrt(8*n+1)             ' get the square root

Console.Write(                 ' write out the answer, either "True" or "False"
                               ' it saves two bytes to do "Sub/End Sub" with "Console.Write()"
                               ' over "Function/End Function" with "return "

              CInt(j)          ' round to the nearest integer (cast to int, but VB rounds instead of truncating)

                     =j)       ' compare against the sqrt
```

Comment: I tried to create a TIO, but I couldn't figure out how to get function arguments to pass it within 5 minutes of trying. I'll try to add one later when I have more time.

Answer (score 0):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 23 bytes

```matlab
@(n)sum(1:sqrt(2*n))==n
```

This is an anonyous function that returns `true` (displayed as `1`) for triangular numbers and `false` (`0`) otherwise.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#S7PV09P776CRp1lcmqthaFVcWFSiYaSVp6lpa5v3P03D0FSTK03DyABMGoJJI83/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## Whitespace, 95 bytes

Visible representation:

```
SSNSNSTNTTNSSSNSSSTNTSSSSNSSNSSSSTNTSSSTSSNSSSTSNTSTSSSNTTTTSSTSNSNTSNNTTSNSSSTNTNSTNSSNSSNTNST
```

Reads the number from stdin. If it is triangular, it outputs 0 to stdout. Otherwise, it outputs 10.

Disassembly:

```
    push 0
     dup
      inum
loop:
     push 1
      add
     dup
      dup
       push 1
        add
       mul
      push 2
       div
      push 0
       get
       sub
      dup
       jz match
      jn loop
     push 1
      pnum
match:
     push 0
      pnum
```

The used technique is a simple brute force search through all possible triangular numbers, but for the given limits that is plenty. Using my own [whitespace JIT compiler](https://github.com/CensoredUsername/whitespace-rs) it takes 0.6 milliseconds to prove that 10<sup>6</sup> is not a triangular number and about 20 seconds to prove that 10<sup>18</sup> is not a triangular number.

Answer (score 0):

## [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents), <s>7</s> 6 bytes

```
?b$
;$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/3z5Jhcta5f9/S0sLS0tDAA)

### Explanation

```
?b$     First program. Checks if the input is triangular.
?       Mode: query. Returns true if the input is in the sequence, and false otherwise.
 b$     Each item in the sequence is the secondary program, passed the current (1-based) index.

;$      Secondary program. Generates triangular numbers.
;       Mode: series. Calculates the sum of the sequence up to the input.
 $      Each item in the sequence is the current (1-based) index.
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES8), 21 bytes

```
a=n=>!((8*n+1)**.5%1)
```

Answer (score 0):

## J, <s>10</s> 9 Bytes

<s>Triangular number of bytes as well :)</s>

-1 Byte thanks to @FrownyFrog

```
0=1|2!inv
```

#### Explanation:

```
    2!       | n choose 2
      inv    | Inverse
0=1|         | Test if it's an integer
```

Could have been 7 bytes if the truthy/falsy values didn't have to be constant.

Works since n choose 2 is n!/2!(n-2)! = n*(n-1)/2

I don't know of any shorter ways to test for integers, previously I had been using `(=<.)`

Comment: `0=1|2!inv` does something like this. `0=1|2&!inv` for a proper function.

Comment: @FrownyFrog Cool! That's real clever

Answer (score 0):

## 05AB1E, 4 bytes

```
ÅTI¢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cGuI56FF//8bWQAA)

Explanation:

```
ÅT     Get list of triangle numbers less than or equal to the implicit input
  I¢   Count occurrences of input in list
```

Comment: In this case the count will give exactly the same output, but just a FYI: there is also a `contains` builtin: `å`. :) (PS: There is already an [05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/177094/52210) using the same approach.)

Answer (score 0):

## [Desmoslang](https://github.com/theRealDadsdy/Desmos-Userscript/tree/main/Desmos%20Programming%20Language), 24 Bytes

```
0^{\mod((8*I+1)^{.5},1OT
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 21 bytes

```perl
$_=sqrt(1+8*$_)!~/\./
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFLDkAwFAXQ@d2FpAOflF7UJ40l2IFEDAwkQtGxpXvO8eu9WxE1D891h5hZl6o5id5iygtxahmME6JEhRoWDVp06EEDEizBCqxB@50@bOfxiB5tbmhE@/0H)