# Is this number tetrahedral?

Tags: code-golf, number, decision-problem

Happy New Year 2024!

2024 is a [**tetrahedral number**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedral_number). A tetrahedral number is a number that can be represented in the form \$n(n+1)(n+2)/6\$ for some positive integer \$n\$. Or, equivalently, they are the sum of the first \$n\$ [triangular numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/122087/9288). They are also the number of objects in a triangular pyramid which has \$n\$ objects on each of its edges.

For example, \$10\$ is a tetrahedral number because \$10 = \frac{3 \times 4 \times 5}{6}\$.

Here are the first few tetrahedral numbers:

```
1, 4, 10, 20, 35, 56, 84, 120, 165, 220, 286, 364, 455, 560, 680, 816, 969, 1140, 1330, 1540, 1771, 2024, ...
```

This is sequence [A000292](https://oeis.org/A000292) in the OEIS.

### Task

Given a positive integer \$n\$, determine whether \$n\$ is a tetrahedral number.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes in each language wins.

This is also a [decision-problem](/questions/tagged/decision-problem), so you may use your language's convention for truthy/falsy (swapping truthy and falsy is allowed), or use two distinct, fixed values to represent true or false.

Answer (score 11):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>32</s> <s>31</s> 29 bytes

```r
function(n)n%in%choose(3:n,3)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/TyNPM081M081OSM/vzhVw9gqT8dY83@ahqGBJheQBBFGIMIYRJho/gcA)

Based on the observation on wiki or OEIS that \$Te_n={{n+2}\choose{3}}\$; `:` ranges downwards for the case of \$n=1\$.

Answer (score 8):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3) `R`, 3 bytes

```
@@c
```

[Try it Online! (link is to literate version)](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyJsUiIsIiIsImN1bS1zdW0gY3VtLXN1bSBjb250YWlucyIsIiIsIjEwIiwiMy40LjAiXQ==)

Simply cumulative sum twice, and check if the input is in that.

R flag casts num to range for cumsum

Comment: Nice. Should the R flag be part of the language name for your answer?

Comment: @NickKennedy it's the result of a new website for the new language - there'll be things I've forgotten like the part that includes flags in the submission :p

Comment: On closer inspection, it was a bug where for some reason, using literate mode completely wiped all flags in the template instead of just removing the literate mode flag. A very silly bug

Answer (score 6):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 6 bytes

```
t:tY+m
```

Try at [**MATL online!**](https://matl.io/?code=t%3AtY%2Bm&inputs=2024&version=22.8.0)

#### How it works

This uses the fact (see [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A000292)) that tetrahedral numbers are

> the convolution of the natural numbers with themselves

It suffices to compute the convolution of the finite sequence 1, 2, ..., *n* with itself. Also, it is not necessary to discard the "transient" (non-valid part) at the end of the convolution result, because all the values there exceed *n* and thus cannot cause false positives.

```
t     % Implicit input: n. Duplicate
:     % Range: gives [1 2 ... n]
t     % Duplicate
Y+    % Convolution
m     % Ismember. Implicit output
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 26 bytes

```
.+
$*
(^(1)|(?<2>1\2)\1)+$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wX0@bS0WLSyNOw1CzRsPexsjOMMZIM8ZQU1vl/39DLiMuYy4TLlMuMy5zLgsuSy5DAwA) Link includes test cases. Explanation: The first stage just converts to unary; the second stage adds successive triangular numbers to see if this will exactly consume the unary number. The `?<2>` syntax reuses capturing group `2`; the equivalent in Perl is to use alternative capture group numbering:

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 33 bytes

```perl
$_=(1x$_)=~/((?|^(1)|(1\2)\1))+$/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lbDsEIlXtO2Tl9Dw74mTsNQs0bDMMZIM8ZQU1NbRf//f0MuIy5jLhMuUy4zLnMuCy5LLkODf/kFJZn5ecX/dQtyAA) Link includes test cases.

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-2) `R`, 23 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 2.875 bytes

```
¦¦c
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyJSPSIsIiIsIsKmwqZjIiwiIiwiMTAiXQ==)

Bitstring:

```
10110100000101111100100
```

Same as my vyxal 3 answer but with the funny haha fracbyte encoding.

Comment: +1 for "funny haha fracbyte encoding"

Answer (score 5):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 41 bytes

```ruby
->n{n*=6;a=(n**3**-1).to_i;n==a*-~a*a+=2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vOk/L1sw60VYjT0vLWEtL11BTryQ/PtM6z9Y2UUu3LlErUdvWqPa/iYFeSWZuanF1TWZNgUJ0pk5adGZsbO1/AA)

Finds the cube root of `n*6` rounded down,then applies the formula `a*(a+1)*(a+2)` to see if this equals `n*6`

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES7), 28 bytes

*-2 thanks to [@tsh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/44718/tsh)*

Returns a falsy value for tetrahedral.

```javascript
n=>(n*=6)+(n**=1/3,~n)**3-~n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dcg7DoMwEEXRnlW80p9AAkRpYNgLInYEsmYQoDR8tm5cnas79f9@HZZx3nKWr4ueIlOn2NBH24Sh8lk/LtbG1PnF0cuigtvAIJRNoiVUr@qd0lqNPQO8Yo3jwCC8SnBFkF86TXbGGw)

#### Method

Computes:

$$k=\left\lfloor (6n)^{1/3}\right\rfloor$$

And tests whether:

$$(k+1)^3-k-1=6n$$

Comment: Since swap truthy falsy is allowed, you can change `==` into `-`. Also, this is 28 bytes `n=>(n*=6)+(n**=1/3,~n)**3-~n` which use \$k(k+1)(k+2)=(k+1)^3-(k+1)\$

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
RÄÄċ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/ocMvhliPd////NzIwMgEA)

A monadic link taking an integer and returning 1 for tetrahedral and 0 for not. Similar to many of the other answers: range, cumsum, cumsum, count.

Answer (score 3):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) <sup>[SBCS](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=0_7_1__IyBTaW5nbGUtYnl0ZSBjaGFyYWN0ZXIgZW5jb2RpbmcgZm9yIFVpdWEgMC44LjAKIyBXcml0dGVuIGhhc3RpbHkgYnkgVG9ieSBCdXNpY2stV2FybmVyLCBAVGJ3IG9uIFN0YWNrIEV4Y2hhbmdlCiMgMjcgRGVjZW1iZXIgMjAyMwojIEFQTCdzICLijbUiIGlzIHVzZWQgYXMgYSBwbGFjZWhvbGRlci4KCkNPTlRST0wg4oaQICJcMOKNteKNteKNteKNteKNteKNteKNteKNteKNtVxu4o214o21XHLijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbUiClBSSU5UQUJMRSDihpAgIiAhXCIjJCUmJygpKissLS4vMDEyMzQ1Njc4OTo7PD0-P0BBQkNERUZHSElKS0xNTk9QUVJTVFVWV1hZWltcXF1eX2BhYmNkZWZnaGlqa2xtbm9wcXJzdHV2d3h5ent8fX7ijbUiClVJVUEg4oaQICLiiJjCrMKxwq_ijLXiiJril4vijIrijIjigYXiiaDiiaTiiaXDl8O34pe_4oG_4oKZ4oan4oal4oig4oSC4qe74paz4oeh4oqi4oeM4pmtwqTii6_ijYnijY_ijZbiipriipviip3ilqHii5XiiY3iip_iioLiio_iiqHihq_imIfihpnihpjihrvil6vilr3ijJXiiIriipfiiKfiiLXiiaHiip7iiqDijaXiipXiipziipDii4XiipniiKnCsOKMheKNnOKKg-KqvuKKk-KLlOKNouKsmuKNo-KNpOKGrOKGq-Kags63z4DPhOKInuK4ruKGkOKVreKUgOKVt-KVr-KfpuKfp-KMnOKMn-KVk-KVn-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)</sup>, 10 bytes

```
∊:\+\++1⇡.
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_7_1__ZiDihpAg4oiKOlwrXCsrMeKHoS4KCmYgOQpmIDEwCuKKmuKItWbih6EzMDAK)

Port of lyxal's [Vyxal 3 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/268900/97916).

```
∊:\+\++1⇡.
         .  # duplicate
        ⇡   # range
      +1    # increment
  \+\+      # cumulative sum twice
∊:          # is the input in this?
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 42 bytes

```python
lambda n:n*6in(y**3-y for y in range(n+2))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3tXISc5NSEhXyrPK0zDLzNCq1tIx1KxXS8osUKhUy8xSKEvPSUzXytI00NaE6wHKZCDlTA02rgqLMvBKNTJ00jUyYugULIDQA)

Returns True/False. Saves a few bytes by shifting the closed formula by 1.

Comment: I was about to suggest the improvement of shifting the closed formula on Joao's answer (which I somehow saw first), but I somehow missed the exponentiation trick.

Answer (score 3):

## [C++](https://isocpp.org/), <strike>63</strike> 57 bytes

(-6 bytes thanks to AZTECCO)

```
[](int n){for(int i=n+3;i--;)n*=n!=-~i*i*~-i/6;return n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYzLboMwEEX38xWTdINBVmweFpFNf6TtwnJINCgMCOxVlPw6Jd10de7VfYR5luHu@bZ9EId7uvToaFrj0vvxE9JKfEP2Y7/OPvS4xosF8ClOGLHbvn4y4ogsHtdp@ZPUcVFZktIKzjs@dPJFOeUvSSdjlz6mhZHtc7Pv8uiJs//tgB1qu8OhVkpZLIpB0DU7xGwQIkwpOjc4d/zm4/6goQatoFRQNdAYaHe7G20aKHeWrYHK1FA371SBaRW02sDZnOEX)

This swaps truthy/falsy, so it returns an integer greater than 0 for non-tetrahedral numbers, and 0 for tetrahedral numbers.

63 byte version:

```
[](int n){for(int i=n+2;i-->0;)if(n==-~i*i*~-i/6)n=0;return n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcyxDoIwFIXhnae44tJCGouDS1teRB2aUsht5JZAOxl5dQQXp/Mv53PTJNzL0rCdkdwrdx40xiXN3o5tkRekAciOfpms87CkThWFzSlCArPdnwwpAfF3H@dfoqH6qlCIViqOPSNjxIoVVqvAy42TkWr2Kc8EpD6bOi6jRWJ/IYCBRu2joZFSKqjrcEinxALnLuakddC6fFC5C18)

Comment: Welcome! And this can be [57](https://tio.run/##RYzLboMwEEX38xWTdINBVmweFpFNf6TtwnJINCgMCOxVlPw6Jd10de7VfYR5luHu@bZ9EId7uvToaFrj0vvxE9JKfEP2Y7/OPvS4xosF8ClOGLHbvn4y4ogsHtdp@ZPUcVFZktIKzjs@dPJFOeUvSSdjlz6mhZHtc7Pv8uiJs//tgB1qu8OhVkpZLIpB0DU7xGwQIkwpOjc4d/zm4/6goQatoFRQNdAYaHe7G20aKHeWrYHK1FA371SBaRW02sDZnOEX "C++ (clang) – Try It Online")

Comment: This can easily be a C function that returns through arguments.

Comment: @qwr like [this](https://tio.run/##RYvLCoMwEEX3fsVooRglVCl0M0l/pO0ixAfjYxRNVqK/ntZVV/fAOdfOs7SD4TZciO3gqxoUTatbajM@I78St8BmrNfZ2BpWV2EUGe8mcKDD65MSuyuLrZmWE4E053ckKVFwpjnW8qCMskPS7YF7wLMZDXH6v3SgocTfKCiLokDI805sp@l1hy7tBVKTxr2wk3dKdUolb05w38MX)? i wasn't planning on switching languages, and i'm not sure if returning through the arguments is allowed

Comment: Yes there's some meta post about it. And you can define C functions instead of full programs. In C++ you have anonymous functions as you did too.

Answer (score 3):

## TI-BASIC, 14 bytes

```
max(Ans=cumSum(cumSum(cumSum(1 or rand(Ans
```

Takes input in `Ans`. Works on numbers that are within the list size limit.

---

#### 20 bytes

```
Input N
int(³√(6N
Ans³+3Ans²+2Ans=6N
```

Based on [Arnauld's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/268930).

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 49 bytes

```python
lambda x:any(x==n*-~n*(n+2)/6for n in range(x+1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZqsQ8z8nMTcpJVGhwioxr1KjwtY2T0u3Lk9LI0/bSFPfLC2/SCFPITNPoSgxLz1Vo0LbUFPzP0gwEyFoaGCgacWloFBQlJlXopGpk6aRCVQEAA)

No extra work, just the original formula

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 47 bytes swapping T/F

```python
lambda x:all(x+n*~n*(n+2)/6for n in range(x+1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZqsQ8z8nMTcpJVGhwioxJ0ejQjtPqy5PSyNP20hT3ywtv0ghTyEzT6EoMS89FShpqKn5HySYiRA0NDDQtOJSUCgoyswr0cjUSdPIBCoCAA)

Comment: You can save two bytes from the first version with `lambda n:n in[j*-~j*(j+2)/6for j in range(n+1)]`

Comment: -2 on top of that with `j*~j*~-~j/6`

Comment: @Jakav Would finally result in [Albert.Lang's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/268923/76323)

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 31 bytes

```
f(k)=∏_{n=1}^k(6k-nnn-3nn-2n)
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dqqxirzaqn)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/uhkwhdwnwy)

Returns `0` if it is a tetrahedral number, otherwise it returns a non-zero integer. For 5 more bytes, you can make it return `0` if it is a tetrahedral number, and `1` otherwise:

#### 36 bytes

```
f(k)=∏_{n=1}^ksgn(6k-nnn-3nn-2n)^2
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/yhasqxhiig)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/assasnly28)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org) + [hgl](https://gitlab.com/wheatwizard/haskell-golfing-library), 12 bytes

```
e*^xc scp<e0
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8GuzNyC_KIShYCi1JzSlFQFDU0umMjS0pI0XYt1abapWnEVyQrFyQU2qQYQwf25iZl5CrYKKflcCgoFRQoqCmkKJgimJUTVggUQGgA)

### Explanation

- `e0` integers from 0 to the input
- `xc scp` perform cumulative sums twice
- `e` determine if the input is an element.

### Reflection

It is infuriating I don't have a way to check for membership in an infinite monotonic list.  I would have sworn I had implemented it, but I've spent a long time looking and I can't find it.

It wouldn't save bytes here, in fact if it were 3 bytes it would make this longer by a byte, but it should exist because it will be useful in the future.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 44 bytes

```perl
$i++while($;=$i*($i+1)*($i+2)/6)<$_;$_=$_==$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYhBCoAgFAX37xx/oUWkVlaYZ3EVJEhJBd2@nwTDDExezzQwRa9ccV0/W0yrIOcpVqIMLf8Y2Vq5UHAUfMETs4ZBhx4DLEZMmKEVjHqPfMdjv7jJ6QM)

Comment: Ah, `-l`, that's how it's done (updates his 33 byte Perl 5 `-p` answer).

Comment: 38 bytes [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dcq9DkAwFAbQ/XuOOxQRLVo/1XgUC0OTRhts4tVdljOdtB1BM3kn7c20OEHWkS@KXPyqLCdfmWyiZT62NY5/cMT2YYUaDVpoGHToMUBJ1PKN6fJxP7lM4QM "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 32 bytes

```hs
f n=elem(6*n)[k^3-k|k<-[1..n+1]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hzzY1JzVXw0wrTzM6O85YN7sm20Y32lBPL0/bMDb2f25iZp6CrUJuYoGvQkFRZl6JgopCWmZOSWqRQpoCSJmhgYFB7H8A)

Check whether \$6n\$ is of the form \$k^3-k\$.

**32 bytes**

```hs
q=scanl1(+)
f n=elem n$q$q[1..n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/v9C2ODkxL8dQQ1uTK00hzzY1JzVXIU@lUKUw2lBPLy/2f25iZp6CrUJuYoGvQkFRZl6JgopCWmZOSWqRQpoCSI2hgYFB7H8A)

Using the cumulative-sum-twice method from other answers.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, <s>34</s> <s>33</s> 32 bytes

Outputs truthy/falsy reversed.

```
k^3-k-6#/.k->⌊(6#)^(1/3)⌋+1&
```

[Try this online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z@gKDOvxCE4NSc1uSQ6KDEvPdXByMDIRMfA1jY7zlg3W9dMWV8vW9fuUU@XhpmyZpyGob6x5qOebm1Dtdj//wE)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Nice first answer!

Comment: [27 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7XznOWFdZzeFRT5eh9qOO2RpmypqPerptbc2U1f4HFGXmlTgEp@akJpdEByXmpac6GBkYmeikxf4HAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), <sup><s>10 9</s></sup>8 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
⊢∊+\⍣2⍤⍳
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=e9S16FFHl3bMo97FRo96lzzq3QwA&f=K0ktLil@1DbhUe9mI1OuEhBPJ9pAzzQ27dAKMI/rUd9UoLy6Olf1o96tj3r2P@pdAZQDsmtBegyMTAE&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog-extended&m=train&n=f)

-1 byte thanks to att.

A tacit function which takes an integer on the right and returns 1 if tetrahedral and 0 if not.
Same method as the Vyxal and Uiua answers.

```
⊢∊+\⍣2⍤⍳­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
      ⍤⍳  # ‎⁡range, then
  +\      # ‎⁢cumulative sums,
    ⍣2    # ‎⁣twice
⊢∊        # ‎⁤input is member
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Comment: `+\⍣2⍤⍳` saves parens

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 41 bytes

```scala
x=>(0 to x).exists(n=>x==n*(n+1)*(n+2)/6)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fYsxTsNAFET7nGJkpdgFDA5ICFlsJOgoQEhAFaX4SWzro_VftLsGR5FPQhMKaLhJbpDbEGJqipnRaOa9f4U5WTr7niSpuDfykky3Gzd7LuYRt8SC1QBYFCXqXVHkq5DjyntaTh6iZ6mmOseTcITZP4HSeSjGZYoMjUS2GGWZ_huBlx0UraiQDPkIwxWHR88kVWPJ3y891bwge9fUs8Ir1l2i91w36PVKFv8QOdSNRDO-ds4WJNrgs4llerHVrRmrDNGh1cdFyyEGJWbcGiMHSg5H-tdP9cm57oGPrs_1us8f)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 20 bytes

```
ＮθＷ‹↨υ¹θ⊞υ⁺Ｌυ↨υ⁰⁼Συθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0xK80Nym1SKNQ05qrPCMzJ1VBwye1uFjDKbE4VaNUR8FQU0ehUFNTIaC0OAPED8gpLQaqyEsvAXKBcjB1BpqaQBMCijLzSjRcC0sTc4o1gktzwUqA2q3//zc0@K9blgMA) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs a Charcoal boolean, i.e. `-` for tetrahedral, nothing if not. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `n`.

```
Ｗ‹↨υ¹θ
```

Until the sum reaches `n`, ...

```
⊞υ⁺Ｌυ↨υ⁰
```

... push successive triangular numbers to the predefined empty list.

```
⁼Συθ
```

See whether `n` was reached exactly.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <s>80 64 55 51 47</s> 45 bytes

```python
lambda x:x*6in[k*~k*~-~k for k in range(x+1)]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3dXMSc5NSEhUqrCq0zDLzorO16oBIty5bIS2_SCFbITNPoSgxLz1Vo0LbUDMWqkkbJJeJkDPUMTQw1LTiUshMU0jTyASxFAqKMvNKgGyIlgULIDQA)

Based off of Aiden Chow's Desmos answer.

Comment: [-3 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NYxNCsIwFIT3PcVbJs-mNBZEAjmCN3ATqbEh5ocQIZ7FTUD0Tt7GSutq-Ib55vGO9zwFX59aHl-3rNn-c7gqdxoVFOFUnrqYwkicimStrdhhYRZxYANatGyLtk3KX86Et2XDKaWNcTGkDD9_Pe10SGDAePhPec-paMBo0MRQKfsZICbj84yLVeuSXw)

Comment: [-9 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3zXMSc5NSEhUqrBLzKjVyEws0oALZVga2tmZaFbrZWnVApFuXrVOUmJeeqlGhbaipqQnVrp2WX6SQqZCZpwCRNNQxNDDUtOJSyExTSNPIBLEUCooy80qAbIiWBQsgNAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), <s>80</s> 75 bytes

```go
func(x int)int{for i:=1;i<=x;i++{if 6*x==i*(i+1)*(i+2){return 1}}
return 0}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hVHbSgMxEMXXfMWwUNi0UTbbdu3FCII-iNBKu28qstSmhLbZErNSWPZLfCmCH-Mn1K9xst0KBS8PmSRnZs45mby-zdLN1lslk3kym8IyUZqo5So19sSTS-sR8pIYkCDeMyuPO9sbmemJvwalLcWVy9SA6gneV2di3VeNRq4kRPW1EKruqwanLoY0N1ObGQ28KEh1DIod5efRh-MspX0KObFGPUNPwN2DE-AMWgx4wCDE1WwzaEcMOg5zAI8QCd0p7CDejFoF0amNDzhcFnPYygCLTjF2kdZ1dYOAF4TcGqxbaN8TQsA4vhjFEI-ux4BXjxL3yEdmHaFJNI6ptJiTdO4g6VtK8NXpXAgOeUklfa_2BOIcMPo1S--1x8AyrMHNZFNakOJQFK4GlzvNSnSfpT-6Gwz_drifQe6mMTzwWQJCBP9YLcsYyGTx_JvdbxOVi-pHN5vd_gU)

Loops over all numbers from \$1\$ to \$x\$ inclusive and sees if \$6x = i(i+1)(i+2)\$.

-5 from Joao-3 by using `int` as the return type instead.

Comment: [-5 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hVHbSgMxEMXXfMWwUNi0UTbbdu3FCII-iNBKu28qstSmhLbZErNSWPZLfCmCH-Mn1K9xst0KBS8PmSRnZs45mby-zdLN1lslk3kym8IyUZqo5So19sSTS-sR8pIYkCDeMyuPO9sbmemJvwalLcWVy9SA6gneV2di3VeNRq4kRPW1EKruqwanLoY0N1ObGQ28KEh1DIod5efRh-MspX0KObFGPUNPwN2DE-AMWgx4wCDE1WwzaEcMOg5zAI8QCd0p7CDejFoF0amNDzhcFnPYygCLTjF2kdZ1dYOAF4TcGqxbaN8TQsA4vhjFEI-ux4BXjxL3yEdmHaFJNI6ptJiTdO4g6VtK8NXpXAgOeUklfa_2BOIcMPo1S--1x8AyrMHNZFNakOJQFK4GlzvNSnSfpT-6Gwz_drifQe6mMTzwWQJCBP9YLcsYyGTx_JvdbxOVi-pHN5vd_gU), uses `int` instead of `bool` to save bytes

Answer (score 1):

## x86 32-bit machine code, 11 bytes

```
99 31 C9 01 CA 41 29 D0 77 F9 C3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVHJTsMwED3HXzEEVbKbpiotp26XnrlwQgJUOV4SI9cpiQOOqv46YdJFiM5h7HmzvOex2O/TXIiuuzdO2EYqWNZemnJcrMk/yJrsFquMy3uMqOBV5SDexHDYbrnHTNZ4td1SqnntBbeWMTDOg6a952xxJLzeAYXnmJJxbsuMW9BEzyMhP0kUygqUCKPekWoecSlByUscoYTzpW4yULyHJUYfHCoSVcoTFgNbENJT7bhxZ84qFyMQBa9gOMTgi5EDAbQ@GWAF6cMIWjwnixP8XRirgCZJgOUKHifshPa2x3d7TeOBgXQNA/Pm4hGgCE0DY@fma8mbe@KiME6BKKWax5d0@KORJRyu1TCYTF9wVruitHG1yZ2SJ8VDptlrSJJ33NtVWAt3OCRsZjeUQFFX1npVs7OwSx730uAfIe2RdN2P0JbndZfuZlN0@BcrbFf2Fw)

Following the `regparm(1)` calling convention, this function takes a number in EAX and returns a number in EAX, which uses reversed truthy/falsy – it is 0 for tetrahedral numbers and nonzero otherwise.

In assembly:

```
f:  cdq             # Set EDX to 0 by sign-extending EAX.
    xor ecx, ecx    # Set ECX to 0.
r:  add edx, ecx    # Add ECX to EDX. EDX will run through the triangular numbers.
    inc ecx         # Add 1 to ECX.
    sub eax, edx    # Subtract EDX from EAX.
    ja r            # Jump back, to repeat, if EAX remains positive.
    ret             # Return.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Raku](https://raku.org), 48 bytes

```perl
->\a{^∞ .map(->\n{(n**3-n)/6}).first(*>=a)-a};
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY7dCoIwFIBf5SAhm7i16dRJ6JNEsptBhD_YvAix694hCC-KnqnbnqRNu_nO73c492evTsP8ri_gayheg9FEfhgp92o8fG8PoLXqkC2bETVBEJMGb9MJU33szwYFZaEwUdPu7129TQVFCZuK-po2rUHYo91gQLc9IB5CFIIIgUfMIk1s7bKYWQiHxCFPczvlwu3EsaMQTkqWTpbZM1xKaWUWiYXJYjK8fjHPa_wB)

Generate the sequence itself until it reaches a value greater than or equal to the input. Then return the difference, i.e., return 0 if it hits the input, and a positive integer otherwise; True/False is therefore swapped.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
LηOηOIå
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f59x2fyDyPLz0/38jAyMTAA) or [verify the first 100 test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/X@xydXPXknhUdskBSV7v/8@57b7A5Hf4aX/df4DAA).

**Explanation:**

Similar as other answers.

```python
L        # Push a list in the range [1, (implicit) input]
 ηOηO    # Cumulative sum twice:
 η       #  Get the prefixes of this list
  O      #  Sum each prefix
   ηO    #  And again
     Iå  # Check if the input is in this list
         # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 76 bytes

```powershell
$a=$b=1;while($b-ge1){$b=$_*6/$a/($a+1)/($a+2);if($b-eq1){return !0};$a++}!1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYpRCoMwEESvssIWjCK60foTPEuJsFUh2DYqfmjOHtfCwAxv3vezs19Gdi6i9cNyPg4ZHfYdmX2cHKfYFwOTOgThK2tLtGWKNif1L63M9L4d/onjed38DEkVjHx5SCiGGAkaoAq0BJ5ANej2Ag)

Answer (score 1):

## APL(NARS), 64 chars

```
r←B w;y;z
y←⌈3√w←w×6⋄r←0⋄→3
y-←1
→2×⍳w<z←y×(y+1)×y+2
→0×⍳w>z⋄r←1
```

9+17+4+19+11+4=64

`f(y)=y×(y+1)×(y+2)=y^3+3y^2+2y` is a crescent function and from `y0=⌈(6w)^(1/3) => (y0)^3≥6w =>(y0)^3+3(y0)^2+2(y0)>6w`
so it is possible begin the loop in that point `y0` and decrease `y0` until `(y0)^3+3(y0)^2+2(y0)≤6w`

```
     a⊂⍨B¨a←⍳123
 1  4  10  20  35  56  84  120
```

it seems is possible to use big rational and big float too

```
      B 45487864677774111x
0
      B 45487864677774111x×(45487864677774111x+1)×(45487864677774111x+2)÷6
1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 50 bytes

```
[1pq]st[0pq]sf[1+dd1+d1+**6/dln=tln<flxx]sx?sn0lxx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/z/asKAwtrgk2gBEpUUbaqekALGhtpaWmX5KTp5tSU6eTVpORUVscYV9cZ4BkPX/v6GhiQEA)

This solution outputs 1 for truthy, and 0 for falsy.

Answer (score 1):

## [Rattle](https://github.com/DRH001/Rattle), <s><sup>27</sup></s> 26 bytes

```
|r`[=#-s+2*~*#/6[\=1q]]3`=
```

[Try it Online!](https://www.drh001.com/rattle/?flags=&code=%7Cr%60%5B%3D%23-s%2B2*%7E*%23%2F6%5B%5C%3D1q%5D%5D3%60%3D&inputs=35)

Outputs 1 if the number is tetrahedral, 0 otherwise.

## Explanation

```
|                    take input
 r`                  set input to "\" (variable)
   [ ... ]3`         loop int("3"+str(N)) times where N is the input. The 3 catches the edge case of 1.

=#                   set the top of the stack to i, where i is the loop count
  -                  decrement
   s                 save to memory
    +2               increment by 2
      *~             multiply by the value in memory (performing (i-1)(i+1))
        *#           multiply by i to obtain (i-1)(i)(i+1), effectively the same 
                          as n(n+1)(n+2) but with shifted indices
          /6         divide by 6
            [\...]   if equal to "\" (the original input)
              =1     set the top of the stack to 1
                q    quit and implicitly print the top of the stack
=                    if the loop exits without quitting, the number is not tetrahedral
                         (set top of stack to 0 then print implicitly)
```

There may be a way to get this shorter. I might come back later to try to get the byte count down (someone else should try too!).

Answer (score 0):

## [YASEPL](https://github.com/madeforlosers/YASEPL-esolang/), 58 bytes

```
!d'(=a`3!c$a+!b$a*c!c+!b*c/6}3,d,2!}1,d+|3`2>"Y"|4`1>"N"`4
```

requires input from stdin (it prompts you) and outputs a Y or N whether the number is tetrahedral or not