# Piles and Piles of Pebbles

Tags: code-golf, optimization

My job is stacking pebbles into triangular piles. I've only been doing this for a century and it is already pretty boring. The worst part is that I label every pile. I know how to decompose pebbles into [piles of maximal size](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/118361/decompose-a-number-into-triangles), but I want to minimize the number of piles. Can you help?

## Task

Given an integer, decompose it into the minimum number of [triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number), and output that minimum number.

#### Triangular Numbers

A triangular number is a number which can be expressed as the sum of the first `n` natural numbers, for some value `n`. Thus the first few triangular numbers are

```
1 3 6 10 15 21 28 36 45 55 66 78 91 105
```

## Example

As an example, let's say the input is `9`. It is not a triangular number, so it cannot be expressed as the sum of `1` triangular number. Thus the minimum number of triangular numbers is `2`, which can be obtained with `[6,3]`, yielding the correct output of `2`.

As another example, let's say the input is `12`. The most obvious solution is to use a greedy algorithm and remove the largest triangular number at a time, yielding `[10,1,1]` and an output of `3`. However, there is a better solution: `[6,6]`, yielding the correct output of `2`.

## Test Cases

```
in out
1 1
2 2
3 1
4 2
5 3
6 1
7 2
8 3
9 2
10 1
11 2
12 2
13 2
14 3
15 1
16 2
17 3
18 2
19 3
20 2
100 2
101 2
5050 1
```

## Rules

- The input integer is between 1 and the maximum integer of your language.
- I can emulate any language with [my pebbles](https://xkcd.com/505/), and I want your code as small as possible because I have nothing but pebbles to keep track of it. Thus this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code **in each language** wins.

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13858/68261) full of pebbles.

Comment: Thematically related: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/95231/natural-pi-0-rock

Comment: [OEIS A061336](https://oeis.org/A061336)

Comment: Not to be confused with [OEIS A057945](https://oeis.org/A057945) (the first difference occurs for `n = 12`).

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>57</s> 49 bytes

```
.+
$*
(^1|1\1)+$
1
(^1|1\1)+(1(?(2)\2))+$
2
11+
3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rco9DoMwGIPh/T0HSF8aqYoTws/UsZdAVTswsHRAjNw9hInBkq3H27Kv/19p7f0tT0/zwD46NMv5Bt3DZC@Lbo7ugojkSaWo1kRHpmdgZEKhGqqPhDqUUY8GNKKJWDVcETnkcAI) Based on my answer to [Three triangular numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132834/). Change the third line to `^(^1|1\1)*$` to support zero input. Edit: Saved 8 (but probably should be more) bytes thanks to @MartinEnder.

Comment: You don't need group `1` in the second stage, and neither group `1` nor `3` in the third stage.

Comment: And then `((?(2)1\2|1))` can be shortened to `(1(?(2)\2))`.

Comment: Actually, it's another three byte shorter to do something weird like this: `^((?<2>)(1\2)+){2}$`. Or `^(()(?<2>1\2)+){2}$` if you prefer.

Comment: @MartinEnder That last version makes my brain ache, but I was able to use your second comment for my linked answer, which was nice.

Comment: I think the last one is actually simpler than even the standard approach because it doesn't have the weird conditional forward reference.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 53 bytes

```
Min[Plus@@@Table[$($+1)/2,{$,#+1}]~FrobeniusSolve~#]&
```

This code is very slow. If you want to test this function, use the following version instead:

```
Min[Plus@@@Table[$($+1)/2,{$,√#+1}]~FrobeniusSolve~#]&
```

[Try it on Wolfram Sandbox](https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com)

#### Explanation

```
Min[Plus@@@Table[$($+1)/2,{$,#+1}]~FrobeniusSolve~#]&  (* input: n *)

           Table[$($+1)/2,{$,#+1}]                     (* Generate the first n triangle numbers *)
                                  ~FrobeniusSolve~#    (* Generate a Frobenius equation from the *)
                                                       (* triangle numbers and find all solutions. *)
    Plus@@@                                            (* Sum each solution set *)
Min                                                    (* Fetch the smallest value *)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Jelly ([fork](https://github.com/miles-cg/jelly/tree/frobenius)), 9 bytes

```
æFR+\$S€Ṃ
```

This relies on a fork where I implemented an inefficient Frobenius solve atom. Can't believe it's already been a year since I last touched it.

### Explanation

```
æFR+\$S€Ṃ  Input: n
æF         Frobenius solve with
     $     Monadic chain
  R          Range, [1, n]
   +\        Cumulative sum, forms the first n triangle numbers
      S€   Sum each
        Ṃ  Minimum
```

Comment: Darn Frobenius solve atom it beat my normal Jelly solution by 6 whole bytes :(

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I need to finish it and make a pull for it.

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>69</s> 58 bytes

```r
function(n)3-n%in%(l=cumsum(1:n))-n%in%outer(c(0,l),l,"+")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcoxCoAwDEDR3VNIQUgwhVRxET2MFAtCjdLawdNHxenD4ycN9WRrDUX8tR0Cgr2VZpMG4uzLnssObhTEH49yrQk8MEWkSKY1qHk5z3i/V8cUsArg2H0ZeGDUBw)

Explanation:

```r
function(n){
 T <- cumsum(1:n)             # first n triangular numbers  [1,3,6]
 S <- outer(c(0,T),T,"+")     # sums of the first n triangular numbers,
                              # AND the first n triangular numbers [1,3,6,2,4,7,4,6,9,7,9,12]
 3 - (n %in% S) - (n %in% T)  # if n is in T, it's also in S, so it's 3-2: return 1
                              # if n is in S but not T, it's 3-1: return 2
                              # if n isn't in S, it's not in T, so 3-0: return 3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), <s>176</s> 154 bytes

### Submission

```
{var l=it
var n=0
while(l>0){n++
val r=mutableListOf(1)
var t=3
var i=3
while(t<=l){r.add(t)
t+=i
i++}
l-=r.lastOrNull{l==it|| r.contains(l-it)}?:r[0]}
n}
```

### Beautified

```
{
    // Make a mutable copy of the input
    var l=it
    // Keep track of the number of items removed
    var n=0
    // While we still need to remove pebbles
    while (l > 0) {
        // Increase removed count
        n++
        // BEGIN: Create a list of triangle numbers
        val r= mutableListOf(1)
        var t = 3
        var i = 3
        while (t<= l) {
            // Add the number to the list and calculate the next one
            r.add(t)
            t+=i
            i++
        }
        // END: Create a list of triangle numbers
        // Get the fitting pebble, or the biggest one if none fit or make a perfect gap
        l -= r.lastOrNull {l==it|| r.contains(l-it)} ?: r[0]
    }
    //Return the number of pebbles
    n
}
```

### Test

```
var r:(Int)->Int =
{var l=it
var n=0
while(l>0){n++
val r=mutableListOf(1)
var t=3
var i=3
while(t<=l){r.add(t)
t+=i
i++}
l-=r.lastOrNull{l==it|| r.contains(l-it)}?:r[0]}
n}

data class TestData(val input:Int, val output:Int)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val tests = listOf(
            TestData(1,1),
            TestData(2,2),
            TestData(3,1),
            TestData(4,2),
            TestData(5,3),
            TestData(6,1),
            TestData(7,2),
            TestData(8,3),
            TestData(9,2),
            TestData(10,1),
            TestData(11,2),
            TestData(12,2),
            TestData(13,2),
            TestData(14,3),
            TestData(15,1),
            TestData(16,2),
            TestData(17,3),
            TestData(18,2),
            TestData(19,3),
            TestData(20,2),
            TestData(100,2),
            TestData(101,2),
            TestData(5050,1)
    )
    tests.map { it to r(it.input) }.filter { it.first.output != it.second }.forEach { println("Failed for ${it.first}, output ${it.second} instead") }
}
```

[TryItOnline](https://tio.run/##fVNNT@MwEL37VwxoD7aSRkk/aKlw0UoLEhJiD8sNcfA2KVi4TmVPFqGQ314mCewJ2wd/zJv3ZjyaeanRaHv8pxy4Nb@xKCYb2kEe295mpEbWX6zM2euzNhU3m1y0NknIbMDJfYPqr6lutcffO16IwRvlbDg1nSMLL6QRrctUWXIUDBOpmU6SjpmJdJlRxHZ3jTGtkRTy/R1ctq0tKm09NxONortcu4f8sWO2O5YKFWyJ5OG@8viLnrzPRttDg2tKP4X@WTf4@RaM7RoLe5Ljyj35Nfx0Tr1d/EGn7dNGQMuAVk9CEvQgwYwfGuxf63@wIi1E@j00TachaBZmzcOsRToLQWdhwWVYcBUWPA@zijwcrCgivEhBilkEm4fTLBaRXM4imsuI5irCOw/zpnmsZlEwUrVFvujrPYDjPvRltlcHaEEjYA2Oa8yGlhfQZTttsHIDSHfnMRvbH05kb/IVjVPZ@9XuSm2fyfFAvY/G8tNrRRNaAiHwo/2id@nn/Iy2kd/RiHmsVHlKIVl3/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 15 bytes

```
`G:Ys@Z^!XsG-}@
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P8HdKrLYISpOMaLYXbfW4f9/QwNDAA)

#### Explanation

```
`         % Do...while
  G:      %   Push range [1 2 3 ... n], where n is the input
  Ys      %   Cumulative sum: gives [1 3 6 ... n*(n+1)/2]
  @Z^     %   Cartesian power with exponent k, where k is iteration index
          %   This gives a k-column matrix where each row is a Cartesian tuple
  !Xs     %   Sum of each row. Gives a column vector
  G-      %   Subtract input from each entry of that vector. This is the loop 
          %   condition. It is truthy if it only contains non-zeros
}         % Finally (execute before exiting the loop)  
  @       %   Push iteration index, k. This is the output
          % End (implicit). Proceeds with next iteration if the top of the
          % stack is truthy
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 bytes

```
0rSƤṗ⁸S⁼¥Ðf⁸ḢTL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9@gKPjYkoc7pz9q3BH8qHHPoaWHJ6QB2Q93LArx@f//vykA)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>75</s> <s>63</s> 61 bytes

```js
f=(n,x=y=0)=>y<n+2?x*x+y*y-8*n-2+!y?f(n,x<n+2?x+1:++y):2-!y:3
```

#### How?

We use the following properties:

- According to [Fermat polygonal number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_polygonal_number_theorem), any positive integer can be expressed as the sum of at most 3 triangular numbers.
- A number ***t*** is triangular if and only if ***8t+1*** is a perfect square (this can easily be proven by solving ***t = n(n+1) / 2***).

Given a positive integer ***n***, it's enough to test whether we can find:

- ***x > 0*** such that ***8n+1 = x²*** (***n*** itself is triangular)
- or ***x > 0*** and ***y > 0***  such that ***8n+2 = x²+y²*** (***n*** is the sum of 2 triangular numbers)

If both tests fail, ***n*** must be the sum of 3 triangular numbers.

```js
f = (n, x = y = 0) =>                 // given n and starting with x = y = 0
  y < n + 2 ?                         // if y is less than the maximum value:
    x * x + y * y - 8 * n - 2 + !y ?  //   if x² + y² does not equal 8n + 2 - !y:
      f(                              //     do a recursive call with:
        n,                            //       - the original input n
        x < n + 2 ? x + 1 : ++y       //       - either x incremented or
      )                               //         y incremented and x set to y
    :                                 //   else:
      2 - !y                          //     return either 1 or 2
  :                                   // else:
    3                                 //   return 3
```

#### Test cases

```js
f=(n,x=y=0)=>y<n+2?x*x+y*y-8*n-2+!y?f(n,x<n+2?x+1:++y):2-!y:3

;[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 100, 101, 5050 ]
.forEach(n => console.log(n + ' --> ' + f(n)))
```